# How can I allocate shared memory for a class with type string and type vector elements

Tags: c++, ipc, shared-memory

I have a class like below

```
class client_info{
    public:
        bool exist = false;
        int ID;
        std::string name;
        std::vector<int> record;
};
```

And I want to allocate a shared memory for a `client_info` array(30 elements) for inter-processes communication.

However, since the some elements of `clinet_info` are `std::string` or `std::vector` type. The size of `client_info` will chang when program run.
`sizeof(client_info)` looks like can't get the correct memory size of `client_info`.

How can I determine the size argument in
`int shmget(key_t key, size_t size, int shmflg);`
Or there are some alternative way to declare a block of shared memory.
For convenience, I don't want to use PIPE or FIFO.

Answer (score 0):

After asking this question, I get some highly similar question: 
[is it possible to place std::vector to shared memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363602/is-it-possible-to-place-stdvector-to-shared-memory)

It's seems you should never put a dynamic data instruction in shared memory.
Try to implement with instruction with static size if you really want to use shared memory.