# Why use stdio.h instead of iostream.h in C++

Tags: c++, c

So I'm at university second semester and we are learning Data Structures. Back in first semester we used to learn C, and now we are moving on C++ (I guess due to the OOP, which allows us to implement those data structures).

But apparently we are still including C's libraries instead of C++'s. I'm aware that stdio is for C and iostream is for C++. I'm wondering why use stdio instead of iostream? is cout << bad/slow/etc?

Comment: `iostream.h` is not a thing in C++.

Comment: It was. A very long time ago.

Comment: You can't implement data structures in C?

Comment: If you did indeed learn C initially, it may be that you are still using the C I/O mechanisms in order to lessen the learning curve and ease the transition. Hopefully at some point you will be instructed in the use of C++ iostreams at some point in the future.

Comment: Well I don't know they want us to use C++ but do not let us use OOP. Instead we must use structs to implement data structures.

Comment: @Kyojin: Oh dear. :( BTW, just to freak you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35258401/560648

Answer (score 7):

It's because your "professor" is used to it, and is teaching obsolete/antiquated techniques.

It won't do you much good in the real world.

This is even more apparent by your use of the name "`iostream.h`" — this suggests you're being taught on Turbo C++ using a DOS emulator, as if it's still 1991. It's not still 1991. In *real* C++ it's just "`iostream`".

The world moved on some twenty years ago.

Well done for asking, though. So so so so so so so so many don't. :(

Comment: sorry, i didn't want to mislead. My mistake. I meant only <iostream>

But even so, for me, what should I use instead of iostream or stdio?

Comment: What's wrong with Turbo C++? It works just like any other IDE would work.

Comment: @stackptr: Other IDEs do not require a _DOS emulator_ to run. They also do not bundle a version of C++ that predates standardisation by almost eight years, and the most recent version by over _twenty_. So, no, it doesn't work just like any other IDE.

Comment: @PreferenceBean if it supports C89, its all good. What's the problem with using a DOS emulator? Most programmers write code in vi/emacs/ex/notepad and compile from the command line.

Comment: @stackptr: Hehe you're funny sweetie :)

Comment: @PreferenceBean How am I funny?

Comment: @stackptr: Aww haha!

Comment: @stackptr Honestly not sure if you are being sarcastic, trolling, or actually mean any of that.

Comment: Sarcastic about @user4581301. I'm not trolling.

Comment: @stackptr The IDE part of Turbo C++ is not the problem. If you prefer to use the IDE, then use it. Maybe you grew up programming with it, and can't read code that isn't yellow-on-blue. Different strokes for different folks, and all that. The *real* problem with Turbo C++ is the *compiler* that it bundles along with the IDE. It is horribly out of date, lacks full support for even the original ISO-standardized C++ (informally known as C++98), cannot produce native Win32 executables, and entrenches bad programming practices due to its anachronisms. Use any IDE you want, but get a new compiler.

Comment: If that's what you mean then you are right @CodyGray. I don't use Turbo C++, nor have I ever used it; I just started this whole argument because I didn't know its compiler was so bad.

Comment: Then why would you make such a firm assertion as _"It works just like any other IDE would work"_ :facepalm:

Comment: @stackptr: FWIW, 15 years in the business, and while I *started* with IDE's, today I write my code in Vim and compile from the command line. I consider that a definite improvement. ;-)