# How do I solve "remove duplicates" question in singly linked list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Here, I have written a code to implement a singly linked list in C++.
Then I have made a function to remove duplicates from the list if any.
My program is working perfectly but when I call remove duplicate function its not working , not giving any results.
I have tried solving it for more  than 10hrs.
I think the problem is on delete function but I don't know how to solve it.

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class node{
    public:
    int data;
    node *next;
    node(int d)
    {
        this->data=d;
        this->next=nullptr;
    }
};

class ll
{
    private:
    node *head=nullptr;
    node *tail=nullptr;
    public:
    void inserthead(int value)
    {
        node *newnode=new node(value);
        if(head==nullptr)
        {
            head=newnode;
            tail=newnode;
        }
        else{
            newnode->next=head;
            head=newnode;
        }
    }
    void inserttail(int value)
    {
        node *newnode=new node(value);
        if(tail==nullptr)
        {
            head=newnode;
            tail=newnode;
        }
        else{
            tail->next=newnode;
            tail=newnode;
        }
    }
    void print()
    {
        node *temp=head;
        while(temp!=nullptr)
        {
            cout<<endl<<temp->data<<endl;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    void deletenode(int value)
    {
        node *currnode=head;
        int c=0;
        while(currnode!=nullptr)
        {
            if(currnode->data==value)
            {
                break;
            }
            currnode=currnode->next;
            c++;
        }
        if(c==0)
        {
            head=head->next;
            delete currnode;
        }
        else if(c!=0 && currnode->next!=nullptr)
        {
            node *temp1=head;
            int ct=0;
            while(ct<c-1)
            {
                temp1=temp1->next;
                ct++;
            }
            ct=0;
            node *temp2=head;
            while(ct<c+1)
            {
                temp2=temp2->next;
                ct++;
            }
            temp1->next=temp2;
            delete currnode;
        }
        else
        {
            node *temp=head;
            int ct=0;
            while(ct<c-1)
            {
                temp=temp->next;
                ct++;
            }
            temp->next=nullptr;
            tail=temp;
            delete currnode;
        }
    }
    void removeduplicates()
    {   
        node *curr=head;
        while(curr!=nullptr)
        {
            node *compare=curr->next;
            while(compare!=nullptr)
            {
                if(compare->data==curr->data)
                {
                    deletenode(compare->data);
                }
                compare=compare->next;
            }
            curr=curr->next;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    ll l1;
    l1.inserthead(10);
    l1.inserthead(10);
    l1.inserttail(9);
    l1.inserttail(8);
    l1.inserttail(11);
    l1.removeduplicates();
    l1.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Of note, if your program was working perfectly, you wouldn't be here asking why it's not working.

Comment: Your delete function is unnecessarily complicated, but it's got the right-ish idea. You only need to try to find the node once, not for each case. You don't need any integers. A pointer will be equivalent to `head` or `tail`. Given that your list is singly linked, you should be tracking *two* nodes. The node to be deleted, and the node before it so you can properly redirect its pointer. In your situation where a node is in the middle of the list, you only consider `temp->next`. Your list is broken once the else block finishes.

Comment: You should probably split your delete function into two. A public function that can take a value, find the node that should be deleted, and a private function that takes a pair of pointers. It seems silly to, within a class function where you already have addresses, to force yourself to search by value in order to delete. Your `removeduplicate()` function also only works if the duplicates are next to each other in the list. Is that intentional? A simple list `{10, 2, 10}` would not remove the extra `10`. You need to track what you've seen already in order to remove all duplicates.

Comment: There are other nitpicks, like the garbage `#include`, the node is an implementation detail of the linked list; it shouldn't be sitting out in the global space like that, `using namespace std;` is a bad practice (it really doesn't help beginners much either). You also have no constructors, no destructors, and as a result are in violation of the Rule of 5.

Comment: Start by not using your own list, but by using std::list. Then use std::remove_if

Comment: I presume it's leetcode-ish question, if a linked list is given and you cannot control the datastructure. Traverse twice, count the duplicate numbers into a `multiset` or `unordered_map` and then remove and decrement the count in second run. If you own the construction, the `multiset/unordered_map` could be managed while inserting/removing an item.

Comment: Side notes: (1) [#include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) (2) [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 2):

Some of the issues:

- In `removeduplicates`, when `deletenode(compare->data)` has been called, the node referenced by `curr` will have been deleted (but see next point), and so the next statement `curr=curr->next;` makes an invalid dereferencing. You can avoid this in many ways. One way is to not use `deletenode` at all (see other points below), but to define a function that will remove the *next* node after a given node. You would call it with `curr` as argument.
  And after that removal you should not do `compare=compare->next;` but `compare=curr->next;`.
- Assuming that `removeduplicates` is only intended to remove duplicates that are *adjacent*, you can still have an issue if a value occurs multiple times, but not always adjacent. Take for instance the list 1→2→1→1: At the third node, your code will call `deletenode(1)`, but that will delete the **first** node, not the "duplicate" one! Again, this means you should not use `deletenode` here, since you don't want to *search* for a value, but indicate exactly which node to delete.
- `deletenode` never updates `tail`. Yet it should do so when it happens to delete the tail node.
- It doesn't happen in your case, but if `deletenode` were called when the list is empty, then `head=head->next;` will dereferrence a null pointer and `delete currnode;` will attempt to free memory pointed by a null pointer.

Some other remarks:

- [Don't include `stdio.h` in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35415019/5459839) but `iostream`
- [Don't use `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5459839)
- [Don't include `bits/stdc++.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5459839)
- Split logic in different functions. This is mostly true for `deletenode`, which really has two parts: searching for the value, and the actual removal. You could have functions like `delete_head`, `delete_successor`, `find`, ...
- In `deletenode`:

  - the test `else if ( c!=0 &&` is unnecessary, as `c` couldn't be zero, as the case has already been dealt with. Remove that condition.
  - Don't use that `c` variable at all. All you need is deal with the boundary case where the list is empty, and where the list starts with the value that needs to be removed.
  - The case where `currnode->next` is not null is not really a special case. You can deal with this case just like with the alternative case.
  - The loop to find `temp2` is unnecessary, as `temp2` will always end up being `currnode->next`. It is a waste of effort.
  - The loop to find `temp` could be omited if in the very first loop you would stop one step earlier. All you really need (in the non-boundary cases) is the node that *precedes* the node to delete. This calls for a function named `delete_successor`
- In `removeduplicates`:

  - It should not use `deletenode`: that function is intended to *search* for a node to be deleted, while here you already know which one has to be deleted (`compare`), so all that  looping in `deletenode` is not relevant for this use case.
  - The previous point also highlights that the name of the function `deletenode` is misleading. It would be the appropriate name is the argument was a node, but as it has to search for a key, it could be better named `delete_first_occurrence` or something similar.
- The idea to maintain a `tail` reference could in some cases be useful, but more often in *doubly* linked lists. In your case it serves no purpose, and only adds the burden to keep it updated, without any benefit. I've kept it in the code below, but if there is no other benefit (in code you have not shared) then ditch it.
- If you're not using camelCase, then use snake_case for your functions. I'd suggest using PascalCase for class names, and using descriptive names (not `ll`, but `LinkedList`). This improves the readability.

#### Proposed correction

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *next = nullptr;
    
    Node(int d): data(d) {}
};

class LinkedList {
private:
    Node *head = nullptr;
    Node *tail = nullptr;

public:
    void insert_head(int value) {
        Node *newnode = new Node(value);
        if (!head) {
            tail = newnode;
        } else {
            newnode->next = head;
        }
        head = newnode;
    }

    void insert_tail(int value) {
        Node *newnode = new Node(value);
        if (!tail) {
            head = newnode;
        } else {
            tail->next = newnode;
        }
        tail = newnode;
    }

    void print()
    {
        Node *temp = head;
        while (temp) {
            std::cout << temp->data << " -> ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        std::cout << "(null)" << std::endl;
    }

    void delete_head() {
        if (!head) { // nothing to delete
            return;
        }
        Node *temp = head;
        head = head-> next;
        delete temp;
        if (!head) {
            tail = nullptr;
        }
    }

    void delete_successor(Node *prevnode) {
        if (!prevnode) { // special case
            return delete_head();
        }
        if (!head || !prevnode->next) { // nothing to delete
            return;
        }
        Node *temp = prevnode->next;
        prevnode->next = prevnode->next->next;
        delete temp;
        if (!prevnode->next) {
            tail = prevnode;
        }
    }

    Node* find_predecessor(int value) {
        if (!head || head->data == value) {
            return nullptr; // Can mean "head has the value"
        }
        Node *prevnode = head;
        while (prevnode->next && prevnode->next->data != value) {
            prevnode = prevnode->next;
        }
        return prevnode; // Could be tail node, meaning "value not found"
    }

    void delete_first_occurrence(int value) {
        delete_successor(find_predecessor(value));
    }

    void remove_duplicates() {   
        Node *curr = head;
        while (curr) {
            while(curr->next && curr->next->data == curr->data) {
                delete_successor(curr);
            }
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList l1;
    l1.insert_head(10);
    l1.insert_head(10);
    l1.insert_tail(9);
    l1.insert_tail(8);
    l1.insert_tail(8);
    l1.insert_tail(11);
    l1.insert_tail(11);
    l1.insert_tail(11);
    l1.insert_tail(8);
    l1.insert_tail(8);
    l1.remove_duplicates();
    l1.print();
    return 0;
}
```

There much more you can do to improve, like using [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106508/5459839), so you don't have to explicitly execute `delete`, but then we come to the point that you should just not implement a linked list from scratch, and use the one from the standard library. But I assume this is an assignment where you're asked to define the linked list data structure yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Note in C++ you would probable not use your own list class but this :

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> values{ 1,2,3,4,3,2,5,6,7,3,2,4,5,6 };
    
    values.sort();
    values.unique();

    for (const auto value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please permit newcomers to learn by doing their own toy projects. We really don't want to breed [inferior software engineers](https://bonkersworld.net/apparent-complexity).

Comment: We should not breed inferior software engineers, we should breed software engineers who know to how write bug-free code and what mechanisms help to do that (like reusing tested code first). This low-level datastructure implementation details IMO should come second. (I don't say they are not important, but in my teams I would rather have more people who can use C++ correctly then ones who know how to implement datastructures from scratch).

Comment: So this anwers is maybe not directly there for OP, but for other people too