# C++ change from struct to classes?

Tags: c++

How can I change from using struct to class? The code doesn't have any problem. But I wanna how can I put put it in classes.
What would you suggest in way of changing it over. There is no problem there. just a simple change over question.

This is my header file in the c++.

```
struct SpaceShip
{
    int ID;
    int x;
    int y;
    int lives;
    int speed;
    int boundx;
    int boundy;
    int score;
};

struct Bullet
{
    int ID;
    int x;
    int y;
    bool live;
    int speed;
};

struct Comet
{
    int ID;
    int x;
    int y;
    bool live;
    int speed;
    int boundx;
    int boundy;
};
```

and this is my main.cpp file.

```
#include <allegro5\allegro.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_primitives.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_font.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_ttf.h>
#include "objects.h"

//GLOBALS==============================
const int WIDTH = 800;
const int HEIGHT = 400;
const int NUM_BULLETS = 5;
const int NUM_COMETS = 10;
enum KEYS { UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT, SPACE };
bool keys[5] = { false, false, false, false, false };

//prototypes
void InitShip(SpaceShip &ship);
void DrawShip(SpaceShip &ship);
void MoveShipUp(SpaceShip &ship);
void MoveShipDown(SpaceShip &ship);
void MoveShipLeft(SpaceShip &ship);
void MoveShipRight(SpaceShip &ship);

void InitBullet(Bullet bullet[], int size);
void DrawBullet(Bullet bullet[], int size);
void FireBullet(Bullet bullet[], int size, SpaceShip &ship);
void UpdateBullet(Bullet bullet[], int size);
void CollideBullet(Bullet bullet[], int bSize, Comet comets[], int cSize, SpaceShip &ship);

void InitComet(Comet comets[], int size);
void DrawComet(Comet comets[], int size);
void StartComet(Comet comets[], int size);
void UpdateComet(Comet comets[], int size);
void CollideComet(Comet comets[], int cSize, SpaceShip &ship);

int main(void)
{
    //primitive variable
    bool done = false;
    bool redraw = true;
    const int FPS = 60;
    bool isGameOver = false;

    //object variables
    SpaceShip ship;
    Bullet bullets[NUM_BULLETS];
    Comet comets[NUM_COMETS];

    //Allegro variables
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *event_queue = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_FONT *font18 = NULL;

    //Initialization Functions
    if (!al_init())                                     //initialize Allegro
        return -1;

    display = al_create_display(WIDTH, HEIGHT);         //create our display object

    if (!display)                                       //test display object
        return -1;

    al_init_primitives_addon();
    al_install_keyboard();
    al_init_font_addon();
    al_init_ttf_addon();

    event_queue = al_create_event_queue();
    timer = al_create_timer(1.0 / FPS);

    srand(time(NULL));
    InitShip(ship);
    InitBullet(bullets, NUM_BULLETS);
    InitComet(comets, NUM_COMETS);

    font18 = al_load_font("arial.ttf", 18, 0);

    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));
    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_display_event_source(display));

    al_start_timer(timer);
    while (!done)
    {
        ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;
        al_wait_for_event(event_queue, &ev);

        if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
        {
            redraw = true;
            if (keys[UP])
                MoveShipUp(ship);
            if (keys[DOWN])
                MoveShipDown(ship);
            if (keys[LEFT])
                MoveShipLeft(ship);
            if (keys[RIGHT])
                MoveShipRight(ship);

            if (!isGameOver)
            {
                UpdateBullet(bullets, NUM_BULLETS);
                StartComet(comets, NUM_COMETS);
                UpdateComet(comets, NUM_COMETS);
                CollideBullet(bullets, NUM_BULLETS, comets, NUM_COMETS, ship);
                CollideComet(comets, NUM_COMETS, ship);

                if (ship.lives <= 0)
                    isGameOver = true;
            }
        }
        else if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE)
        {
            done = true;
        }
        else if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN)
        {
            switch (ev.keyboard.keycode)
            {
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE:
                done = true;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_UP:
                keys[UP] = true;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN:
                keys[DOWN] = true;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_LEFT:
                keys[LEFT] = true;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_RIGHT:
                keys[RIGHT] = true;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_SPACE:
                keys[SPACE] = true;
                FireBullet(bullets, NUM_BULLETS, ship);
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP)
        {
            switch (ev.keyboard.keycode)
            {
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE:
                done = true;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_UP:
                keys[UP] = false;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN:
                keys[DOWN] = false;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_LEFT:
                keys[LEFT] = false;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_RIGHT:
                keys[RIGHT] = false;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_SPACE:
                keys[SPACE] = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (redraw && al_is_event_queue_empty(event_queue))
        {
            redraw = false;

            if (!isGameOver)
            {
                DrawShip(ship);
                DrawBullet(bullets, NUM_BULLETS);
                DrawComet(comets, NUM_COMETS);

                al_draw_textf(font18, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 255), 5, 5, 0, "Player has %i lives left. Player has destroyed %i objects", ship.lives, ship.score);
            }
            else
            {
                al_draw_textf(font18, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 255), WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "Game Over. Final Score: %i", ship.score);
            }

            al_flip_display();
            al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
        }
    }

    al_destroy_event_queue(event_queue);
    al_destroy_timer(timer);
    al_destroy_font(font18);
    al_destroy_display(display);                        //destroy our display object

    return 0;
}

void InitShip(SpaceShip &ship)
{
    ship.x = 20;
    ship.y = HEIGHT / 2;
    ship.ID = PLAYER;
    ship.lives = 3;
    ship.speed = 7;
    ship.boundx = 6;
    ship.boundy = 7;
    ship.score = 0;
}
void DrawShip(SpaceShip &ship)
{
    al_draw_filled_rectangle(ship.x, ship.y - 9, ship.x + 10, ship.y - 7, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 0));
    al_draw_filled_rectangle(ship.x, ship.y + 9, ship.x + 10, ship.y + 7, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 0));

    al_draw_filled_triangle(ship.x - 12, ship.y - 17, ship.x + 12, ship.y, ship.x - 12, ship.y + 17, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0));
    al_draw_filled_rectangle(ship.x - 12, ship.y - 2, ship.x + 15, ship.y + 2, al_map_rgb(0, 0, 255));
}
void MoveShipUp(SpaceShip &ship)
{
    ship.y -= ship.speed;
    if (ship.y < 0)
        ship.y = 0;
}
void MoveShipDown(SpaceShip &ship)
{
    ship.y += ship.speed;
    if (ship.y > HEIGHT)
        ship.y = HEIGHT;
}
void MoveShipLeft(SpaceShip &ship)
{
    ship.x -= ship.speed;
    if (ship.x < 0)
        ship.x = 0;
}
void MoveShipRight(SpaceShip &ship)
{
    ship.x += ship.speed;
    if (ship.x > 300)
        ship.x = 300;
}

void InitBullet(Bullet bullet[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        bullet[i].ID = BULLET;
        bullet[i].speed = 10;
        bullet[i].live = false;
    }
}
void DrawBullet(Bullet bullet[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (bullet[i].live)
            al_draw_filled_circle(bullet[i].x, bullet[i].y, 2, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255));
    }
}
void FireBullet(Bullet bullet[], int size, SpaceShip &ship)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (!bullet[i].live)
        {
            bullet[i].x = ship.x + 17;
            bullet[i].y = ship.y;
            bullet[i].live = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
void UpdateBullet(Bullet bullet[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (bullet[i].live)
        {
            bullet[i].x += bullet[i].speed;
            if (bullet[i].x > WIDTH)
                bullet[i].live = false;
        }
    }
}
void CollideBullet(Bullet bullet[], int bSize, Comet comets[], int cSize, SpaceShip &ship)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bSize; i++)
    {
        if (bullet[i].live)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cSize; j++)
            {
                if (comets[j].live)
                {
                    if (bullet[i].x >(comets[j].x - comets[j].boundx) &&
                        bullet[i].x < (comets[j].x + comets[j].boundx) &&
                        bullet[i].y >(comets[j].y - comets[j].boundy) &&
                        bullet[i].y < (comets[j].y + comets[j].boundy))
                    {
                        bullet[i].live = false;
                        comets[j].live = false;

                        ship.score++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void InitComet(Comet comets[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        comets[i].ID = ENEMY;
        comets[i].live = false;
        comets[i].speed = 5;
        comets[i].boundx = 18;
        comets[i].boundy = 18;
    }
}
void DrawComet(Comet comets[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (comets[i].live)
        {
            al_draw_filled_circle(comets[i].x, comets[i].y, 20, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 0));
        }
    }
}
void StartComet(Comet comets[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (!comets[i].live)
        {
            if (rand() % 500 == 0)
            {
                comets[i].live = true;
                comets[i].x = WIDTH;
                comets[i].y = 30 + rand() % (HEIGHT - 60);

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
void UpdateComet(Comet comets[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (comets[i].live)
        {
            comets[i].x -= comets[i].speed;
        }
    }
}
void CollideComet(Comet comets[], int cSize, SpaceShip &ship)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cSize; i++)
    {
        if (comets[i].live)
        {
            if (comets[i].x - comets[i].boundx < ship.x + ship.boundx &&
                comets[i].x + comets[i].boundx > ship.x - ship.boundx &&
                comets[i].y - comets[i].boundy < ship.y + ship.boundy &&
                comets[i].y + comets[i].boundy > ship.y - ship.boundy)
            {
                ship.lives--;
                comets[i].live = false;
            }
            else if (comets[i].x < 0)
            {
                comets[i].live = false;
                ship.lives--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add the free functions corresponding to the struct as member functions of a class.

Comment: change **struct** to **class** and add **public** class access modifier at the start to make it work as it is

Answer (score 0):

The *only* difference between a `struct` and a `class` is that by default, the members of a `struct` are `public` but the members of a `class` are `private`.

So in that sense, your `struct`s are *already* classes.

You can add member functions to your `struct`s as you see fit. In order to facilitate *encapsulation*, eventually you'll add constructors and accessors to your member variables. The member variables themselves will be marked `private`. At this point, you end up with something that looks like a typical C++ `class`

Comment: And this is reinforced by the language: [`std::is_class<SpaceShip>::value` is `true`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34108140/560648)! These are already classes indeed.