# I know struct is a class but the code says No

Tags: c++, class, struct, types, type-traits

I was trying to convince a friend that `struct` is just a `class` in the modern C++. After a lot of arguing and resource exchange (including some SO Q&A), I came into an idea to prove it through code, so I wrote:

```
class A {};
struct B {};

int main()
{
    cout << (is_class<A>::value ? "Yes" : "No") << "\n";  // output Yes
    cout << (is_class<B>::value ? "Yes" : "No") << "\n";  // output Yes

    cout << (is_same<A,B>::value ? "Yes" : "No") << "\n"; // output No ???
}
```

As you can see, I was surprised from the third `cout` line output. So, I am stuck here now, and I do not know if am I right or not.

Is a `struct` a `class` or not?
Why does the code show two different things?

Update:

I pretty understand what is the difference between struct and class. What confused me is the difference between the `is_class` and `is_same` as answers showed. What should I have done if not asking here???
What is this site for? Why some users tend to claim questions are not useful without even put a comment to specify where it is not conforming with the asking policy?

Remember, We not all people speaks English fluently. and not all people have years of the experience.

Thanks for all who answer or comment.

Comment: Now try with `class B{};`. Is a class not a class?

Comment: Helpful reading: [What are the differences between struct and class in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)

Comment: [computer says no](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJQ3TM-p2QI) isn't really helpful for diagnosis.

Comment: You are not cleared for that information, Citizen.

Comment: @user4581301: Shame so many of those answers are wrong. Prefer these links: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36917400/560648 http://stackoverflow.com/a/34108140/560648

Comment: Some SO users seem to spend most of their time just looking for questions to down vote. Your question seems pretty reasonable to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At first, you are right.  **a struct is just a class** under the hood.

Some indications:

1-  You can forward declare one of them and then define it with the other one (although some compliers may issue a warning).

```
class A;     // declaration of A with class
struct A { /* definition of A with struct */ } ;
```

2-  `is_class<>` returns true for both.
3-  There is no `is_struct<>` in `<type_traits>`.
4-  In most cases, the two keywords are interchangeable. (e.g: in scoped enum).

However, they have important syntactic differences:

`struct`

- Grants public access to its members by default.
- Backward compatible with C if used without C++ features.

`class`

- Grants private access to its members by default.
- Not compatible with C.

Which one to use is a matter of convention and/or convenience.

Generally, I prefer using `struct` as an aggregate of data (record). And `class` for other uses.

Now we come to your second question:

> Why does the code show two different things?

It does not.

Because `is_class<>` is not about types but rather it is about **type categories**. (i.e. `is_class<x>` checks if the **type x** is a class or not) whereas `is_same<>` is about types themselves ((i.e. `is_same<x, y>` checks if **type x** is as same as **type y** or not))

If you change `struct` in your test code into `class`, `is_same<>` would still outputs “No”  because `A` is a type and `B` is another type even if they both have the same type category which is `class`.

Based on your code:

```
A a;  // a is of type A
B b; // b is of type B
// Can we say that a and b of the same type?
// No. And this is what is_same<> checks.
```

Comment: Thanks @juanchopanza for the correction about the default constructor/destructor. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Handy links: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36917400/560648 http://stackoverflow.com/a/34108140/560648

Answer (score 7):

You are confused as to what `std::is_same<>` is for.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same:

> If T and U name the same type with the same const-volatile
>   qualifications, provides the member constant value equal to true.
>   Otherwise value is false.

Clearly `A` and `B` are different classes; with that last sentence I am implying that you are indeed correct in that a `struct` is the same as a `class`; the difference being that a `struct` has a default access of `public` for its members, whereas a `class` has a default of `private` instead.

Don't take my word for it, the C++ standard states the following in 10.1.7.3 Elaborated type specifiers [dcl.type.elab]:

> [...] either the class or struct class-key shall be used to refer to a
>   class declared using the class or struct class-key.

Reference: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with `struct` vs `class`.

> ```
> cout << (is_class<A>::value ? "Yes" : "No") << "\n";  // output Yes
> ```

Yes, because `A` is a class.

> ```
> cout << (is_class<B>::value ? "Yes" : "No") << "\n";  // output Yes
> ```

Yes, because `B` is also a class *([it rea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36917400/560648)[lly is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34108140/560648))*.

> ```
> cout << (is_same<A,B>::value ? "Yes" : "No") << "\n"; // output No ???
> ```

No, because they're not *the same class*.

`A` and `B` are two different types.

It's `std::is_same`, not `std::is_similar`.

Comment: thanks @BoundaryImposition for your great posts. I checked them and they are really good. So, if I need to check such a thing I can use something like: `if (is_class(A) && (is_class(B))`. ... I looked for `is_similar`, but it is not there. so I guess you mention it for clarity. But what if I need such functionality?

Comment: @KamalZidan: Yep. And yep `std::is_similar` doesn't exist; as far as I know there's no way (or reason) to implement it.