# Initializing a const pointer to a structure c++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, initializing

I am a beginner in C++, and got confused about the initialization of const pointers declared in headers. To give but one example, I have in my header a structure and a class like:

```
/* header file.h */
typedef struct A{ ... } A;

class myClass{
    protected:
        A *const myPtrA;
}
```

And would like to instantiate the content of myPtrA, for instance in a constructor, knowing that A is a quite complicated structure composed of substructures, and needs to be dynamically instantiated:

```
/* source file.cpp */
#include file.h

myClass::myClass() {
   A *tmpA = new A;
   *myPtrA = *tmpA;
}
```

Is this the good way to initialize my const pointer myPtrA? And to the extent each new call needs a dedicated delete call, can I delete my pointer tmpA immediately after the line *myPtrA = *a; without risk of losing the content pointed by myPtrA?

Thank you in advance for your time (and pardon my English ;) )

qroh

Comment: [Find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read about *constructor initializer lists*.

Comment: By the way, in C++ a `struct` is just like a class, the only difference being the default visibility (`public` for `struct`, `private` for `class`). That means you don't need `typedef` for a `struct`.

Comment: ``typedef struct A { ... } A;`` is the C way of defining a struct. In C++ you define it like you do for classes: ``struct A{...};``. The only difference between struct and classes in C++ is the default visibility.

Comment: _knowing that A is a quite complicated structure composed of substructures, and needs to be dynamically instantiated_ Umm.. Why can't you initialize it within _initializer list_ via the call of the constructor? Why do you think, that you need dynamic allocation here. Note: The example, that you show, exhibits undefined behavior, because `myPtrA` is not initialized. And no, `*myPtrA = *tmpA;` is **not** an initialization of it. That line is trying to _dereference_ pointer, that was never initialized.

Comment: Why do you even have a pointer there in the first place?

Comment: Well ok for struct typedef :) it's noted.

Comment: Well, I simplified the problem because my structure A is defined in another header associated with a C file (that's why I let this semantic with typedef, sorry for that).

To be more precise, I need to create a cpp wrapper over a c file. My cpp constructor must begin by calling the wrapped c constructor, and the latter takes as an argument a const pointer to structure A.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: No, a `struct` **is** a class.

Comment: @nefas: Please don't spread [misconceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34108140/560648).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> *myPtrA = *tmpA;
> ```
>
> Is this the good way to initialize my const pointer myPtrA?

No. You haven't initialized `myPtrA` at all. It was default-initialized and therefore has indeterminate value. Dereferencing the pointer with indeterminate value (`*myPtrA`) has undefined behaviour.

> can I delete my pointer tmpA immediately after the line *myPtrA = *a; without risk of losing the content pointed by myPtrA?

Yes, it is safe. The object pointed by `myPtrA` is copy (by assignment) of the one pointed by `tmpA`. However, it is completely pointless to allocate a dynamic object, copy it and then detroy it in the first place, when you could simply create/modify the copy directly.

Here is an example of how to correctly initialize the member pointer:

```
class myClass{
    protected:
        A *const myPtrA = new A;
};
```

---

PS. While it is useful to learn how to do this, you should hardly ever manage memory manually in actual programs. Instead use RAII containers such as `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it very clear!

"it is completely pointless to allocate a dynamic object, copy it and then detroy it in the first place"

I agree, but I wanted to make sure it's pointless ;)

Thanks again