# What is the function structname (void){num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();} for in c++? How can I understand it?

Tags: c++

When I reading code in project of my interest, I come across the function in struct without function name, and maybe it is not the lambda expression capture->return-type{body} either, i just donnot know what kind of this function is?

```
// file.cc
struct AppSettings
{

    std::string mesh_name;

    std::size_t num_threads;

    AppSettings (void)
    {
        num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    }
};
```

anyone knows how should i understand this function
`AppSettings (void) {num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();}`?

Comment: If you know about lambda expressions but not constructors, you may have begun your C++ studies at the wrong end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i am almost a beginner of c++... i am used to the common usage of the constructor but forget the default one

Answer (score 2):

That is [the class's constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)).

This is a special member function that's automatically executed when an instance of the class is instantiated.

Giving it the parameter list `(void)` is an old-fashioned way of giving it the parameter list `()`, i.e. no parameters.

For more information, consult the chapter in [your C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) about classes (bearing in mind that [`struct` introduces a *class*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34108140/560648)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I really should learn the c++ primer more carefully....

Comment: @PhilLee Might not be a bad idea ;)