# Difference between struct and class in older c++ versions

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++98

Was it always in C++ that `class` and `struct` are different only by the default access specifier? Or in some early version C++ `struct` was more like C `struct`?

Comment: This question applies to all versions of C++: [When should you use a class vs a struct in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585/when-should-you-use-a-class-vs-a-struct-in-c)

Comment: I think here you can find a answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty much always.

It has been this way since long before standardisation, [practically since the first draft revisions in the 80s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34108140/4386278).

Frustratingly, [Stroustrup's "A History of C++"](https://www.stroustrup.com/hopl2.pdf) does not discuss this, but types known as "classes", defined using the `struct` keyword, could be found as early as ["The C++ Programming Language - Reference Manual"](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_e/doc/ReferenceManual.pdf), which was the first specification following the "C with Classes" research phase and thus effectively the first pre-standard C++ revision:

> *classes* containing a sequence of objects of various types, a set of functions for manipulating these objects, and a set of restrictions on the access to these objects and functions;
>
> *structures* which are classes without access restrictions

This was known as "Release E", and [came in November 1984](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/index.html#cfront).

By [Release 2.0](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_2.0/doc/ProductReferenceManual.pdf) in 1989, this had been relaxed to the rule we have today:

> *structures* which are classes without default access restrictions

For a temporal reference, the first version of what we now call "C++" was standardised in 1998.

Answer (score 1):

By the standard yes, in practice I too have heard that compilers attempted (or still attempt?) to handle them differently internally by prioritizing different optimization paths.

Comment: [Visual C++ mangles them differently, which results in some non-compliance.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36917400/4386278)