# How to check if a template parameter is a struct/class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, class-template

For a small example like this, I want to only accept `T` if `T` is a `struct/class` and reject builtin types like 'int', 'char', 'bool' etc.

```
template<typename T>
struct MyStruct
{
   T t;
};
```

Comment: [`std::is_class`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_class)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for [`std::is_class`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_class) traits from [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) header. Which

> Checks whether `T` is a non-union class type. Provides the member
> constant value which is equal to `true`, if `T` is a class type (but not
> union). Otherwise, value is equal to `false`.

---

For instance, you can [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) for the template type `T` like follows:

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_class

template<typename T>
struct MyStruct
{
   static_assert(std::is_class<T>::value, " T must be struct/class type!");
   T t;
};
```

**([See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rToKG3))**

---

### [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) [concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) Updates

In C++20, one can provide a concept using `std::is_class` as follows too.

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_class

template <class T> // concept
concept is_class = std::is_class<T>::value;

template<is_class T> // use the concept
struct MyStruct
{
   T t;
};
```

**([See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jobx87))**

Comment: [And, yes, this works for "structs" too; and, no, there shouldn't be a separate trait for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34108140/4386278) (because "structs" don't exist)