# C++ - CCLS Showing False Error on Concept Keyword

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I'm trying to restrict types on a certain struct to only classes or structs. I did some digging and found this answer [How To check if a template parameter is a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63198504/how-to-check-if-a-template-parameter-is-a-struct-class). It works, and I've compiled it, but ccls is still showing an error:

`unknown type name 'concept'`

Is it because of ccls just out-of-date or is there something else?

here is my code:

```
template<typename T> concept is_object = std::is_class<T>::value;

template<is_object T>
struct TypeDiscriptor_Object{
// code
}
```

Comment: You didn't set the tool up to use C++20 or later or it doesn't support C++20 concepts. Otherwise it would know that `concept` is a keyword.