# std::vector, std::map, std::string, etc. as struct members?

Tags: c++, memory, std

I'm quite used to C# in which `struct`s are best left to only having members of `unmanaged` types so that the `sizeof()` the `struct` is pre-determined and can be treated entirely as a value type.

When one writes something like:

`std::vector<T> myVec;`

as a member of a `struct` in a C++ header file, it is my understanding that this allocates an instance of the `std::vector<T>` `class` on the stack rather than where `class`es typically go on the heap to be referenced via pointers (although I'm aware in C++ that `struct` and `class` definitions are much more similar than they are in C#).

What I'm wondering is what are the general memory implications of using reference types like `std::vector<T>`, `std::string`, `std::map<T,T>` as though they were value types that belong on the stack like this? Most importantly:

1. Will my `struct` still be of a fixed size if I use these example types as members of a `struct`?
2. Would I be better off using pointers to these types as members for my `struct` so that I know the member is 8 bytes large on (for example) a 64-bit machine?
3. Will a stack-allocated instance of my `struct` set like this (`structInstA = structInstB`) have members that are shallow copies of my various `std::` members or will they be unique members with the same elements?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What you claim about C# structs is pretty wrong, there is nothing wrong with storing managed types in them (and I've done so extensively on some projects). Similarly having a `std::vector` member in a C++ class (which `struct`s are) doesn't specify anything about "heap" or "stack" - they are simply allocated as part of an object

Comment: A `std::vector` is of a fixed size, so as a `struct` member your struct still has a fixed size - the members the vector stores it dynamically allocates itself, but that doesn't change the size of the vector object.

Comment: Multiple things you misunderstand. For one, C++ doesn't have such a thing as reference types.

Comment: C++ does not attribute different storages to `struct` or `class`. Local variables, function arguments and return values are stored on the stack. Everything allocated (indirectly) with the `new` operator is allocated on the heap. You can think of `std::vector` and friends as fixed-size objects that reference a heap allocation for their storage.

Comment: I'm all but shocked, amazed, and thankful at the speed and accuracy with which responses are coming in. Thanks one and all so far!

Comment: When you visualize a vector "on the stack" as you say, you should imagine three pointers. That is how they usually work - a pointer to the start, and pointer to the end of items that exist, and a pointer to the end of the capacity. You aren't picturing giant blocks of RAM allocated from the stack, are you?

Comment: As for question 3: yes, the autogenerated copy constructor will take care of that. If you write your own and don't do something boneheaded, it will just properly copy.

Comment: The collections you mention are all fixed size objects.  The data they contain are not part of the objects themselves, they are heap allocated and pointers are used by the class to keep track of it all.

Comment: Addendum on point 3: Familiarize yourself with the [Rule of three (and friends)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You cannot write efficient and effective C++ code without a good grip on these rules. Your goal should be to use the Rule of Zero except for when the structure must directly manage a resource.

Comment: @MarkRansom @doug65536 yeah I should've clarified, I think one of my previous questions on the website would give some insight as to my understanding of `std::vector` that the vector itself is on the stack whereas the data the vector stores is on the heap with each element in the vector being a pointer offset from the first pointer in the vector that is `elem size in bytes * index` bytes of memory away from the start of the vector's heap allocation.

Comment: Don't guess your way through C++, read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) instead. Contrary to C#, winging it with C++ will only end in tears. And no, that's not a slight against C#, it's a criticism of C++.

Comment: @PasserBy Thanks for the reading material! 'A Tour of C++' sounds like the best one for me to start with especially considering its author. As someone who hasn't read a thing since high school English class, my attention span would contest with the notion your link offers that 200+ pages is a "quick" read, but I will try and absorb the technobabble of it all the best I can and hopefully return to my development witha  firmer understanding of C++.

Comment: When I'm spinning up a new programmer at work, I give them Stroustrup's  Programming: Practice and Principles *and* Tour of C++ because it's more up-to-date on the language details. I found Tour to be a bit too terse on its own. There are idioms and thought details that Tour doesn't take the time to cover. Another good one, once you have a solid grip on the syntax, is Meyers's Effective Modern C++.

Comment: "in C++ that struct and class definitions are much more similar": Where is Lundin when you need him?? The two are the same, only with different default privacy.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Probably not a good time to say I don't know who Lundin is, but yeah I reworded this question a dozen times because usually I think I know what I'm talking about with anything to do with programming and then I do not. Got it now though!

Comment: @SpringE.Thing Funny, I confused the user -- I meant [Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit). They must strike a similar chord in me. I had an argument [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35698862/3150802) about classes and structs. In a comment to a different answer Lightness had claimed "C++ does not have structs" which is simply not true in any conceivable meaning of the word, as I laid out in may answer. But then he is of course right that they are the same in C++, hence my "where art thou in my times of need!?" ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Will my struct still be of a fixed size if I use these example types as members of a struct?

The struct itself, in C++, is *always* of fixed size; variable-length structs are supported as an extension by some compilers, but it's not part of the language standard, and none of these types need it.

`std::vector`, `std::map`, `std::string` and company perform dynamic memory allocation, so the struct itself only stores a handful of pointers (e.g. for `vector`, a start, end, and end of allocated capacity pointer), and any variable length data is allocated from the heap as needed.

> 2. Would I be better off using pointers to these types as members for my struct so that I know the member is 8 bytes large on (for example) a 64-bit machine?

No, using pointers will just fragment your memory further. The main reason to consider pointers would be if you want to share the *same* container across multiple instances of your struct (e.g. with `std::shared_ptr`), or in the specific case of `std::string`, to allow ownership to be transferred without potentially invalidating `std::string_view`s of the underlying data (the small string optimization used in some implementations means that iterators and views of the string's data can be invalidated by a move).

> 3. Will a stack-allocated instance of my struct set like this (structInstA = structInstB) have members that are shallow copies of my various std:: members or will they be unique members with the same elements?

If you store them as raw values, not pointers, the copies (stack-allocated or otherwise) will be (typically) *deep* copies of the various contained collections. If you instead used `std::shared_ptr`-wrapped versions of the collections, it would be doing extremely shallow copies (the copy would refer to the exact same collection as the original, but either one could be reassigned to a new version of the collection to break the connection).

---

Additional notes:

C++ structs and classes are *identical*, except for *one* difference: struct members have public visibility by default, classes default to private visibility. Both can be on the stack (if declared as non-`static`, non-`constexpr` in the body of a function, without `new` or other allocation helpers like `std::make_shared` or the like), both can be on the heap (with `new`/`std::make_shared`/etc.), or they can be in global memory (if declared outside functions, or inside functions as `static`s).

But in all of the container types you mention, the bit stored on the stack/heap/global memory is trivial, just a handful of pointers. All the data they contain is on the heap, managed automatically by the class itself. When copied to a new instance of the type, new heap memory is allocated, all the contained data is copied (which might invoke additional heap allocations), and the two instances are utterly unrelated thereafter (some copy constructors might not operate as deep copies, as with `shared_ptr`s, but they're the exception, not the rule). That's why `std::move` exists; if you don't *need* two copies of the data, you just want to transfer ownership of the data (e.g. you've populated a `std::vector` and want to hand it off to some other `struct` that will own it from there on out), `std::move` reduces the cost from allocating and deepcopying everything (potentially very expensive) to just copying the pointers over and zeroing the source pointers (typically a matter of half a dozen processor cycles).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer to each question! From responses to the original question in its comments section, I might reel it back a bit and read some supplementary material before going on my merry way, but this sums up what I needed well : )

Comment: @SpringE.Thing whatever you do, just stay away from raw pointers and `new` keyword for at least 2 years. There are almost always better alternatives. When you've internalized object lifetime semantics and **RAII** - as well as **rule 350** - you can cautiously start exercising raw pointers in toy programs. Before that, it'll just be a vendetta against your feet.