# Is value in std::unordered_map<std::string, int> initialised by default or not?

Tags: c++, initialization, unordered-map

I have a following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map;
  std::cout << map["foo"]; // -> 0

  return 0;
}
```

I am using `map["foo"]` without initialisation.
Is this code valid or UB?

Edit: I tried to compile in godbolt and got `0` output with clang and gcc (trunk version) https://godbolt.org/z/KeWq7nbob.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [map<int,int> default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667355/mapint-int-default-values). Also [std::map default value for build-in type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4523959/11082165)

Comment: you need to read some docs https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: It's valid. I'm not sure exactly what you think is uninitialized in this code. `map` is initialized, and so is the map entry you added using the `[]` operator.

Comment: @john: `int`s default constructor is "uninitialized". The confusion is caused by the assumption that the map "default constructs" the `int`. Which is a fair confusion to have, because many people incorrectly say that maps default initialize values.

Comment: I wouldn't say that C++ reference page is clear about what sort of initialization happens when the key is "inserted". This sort of question is a good one to have on SO. It just happens to be a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `operator[]` does not find the value with given key one is inserted into the map. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> Inserts `value_type(key, T())` if the key does not exist. [...]

`T()` is [Zero-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization). For `int` this bullet applies:

> If `T` is a scalar type, the object is initialized to the value obtained by explicitly converting the integer literal `​0`​ (zero) to `T`.

All is fine in your code. `map["foo"]` returns a reference to `0` after inserting that `0` together with the key constructed from the string literal `"foo"` into the map. This is the intended use of `std::map::operator[]`. If you want to check if an element exists in the map use `std::map::find`. If you want to find an existing one or insert if none is present, use `std::map::insert`.