# C++ - struct vs. class

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [C/C++ Struct vs Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750270/c-c-struct-vs-class)
> [What are POD types in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c)

In the **C++ In a Nutshell book**, in **chapter 6: classes**, unders **Access specifiers**, mentioned the following:

> In a class definition, the default
> access for members and base classes is
> private. In a struct definition, the
> default is public. **That is the only
> difference between a class and a
> struct**, although by convention, some
> programmers use struct only for **POD
> classes** and use class for **all other
> classes**.

My questions here are:

- Isn't there another difference between classes and structs in that structs don't hold functions and just hold data?
- What are POD classes? And, what is meant by all other classes here? Are there then special classes?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750270/c-c-struct-vs-class

Comment: @aali == duplicate of @SWEngineer ?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/#struct_and_union

Answer (score 94):

The other difference is that

```
template<class T> ...
```

is allowed, but

```
template<struct T> ...
```

is not.

Comment: +1 for unique approach

Comment: The official way to use template is `template<typename T>`, `template<class T>` is kinda misleading, it's there because of legacy.

Comment: then add another difference between int and class too..!! `template<class T> ... works` but `template<int T> ... not`

Comment: @UnKnown, of course that works, we just call the integers `I`, `J`, `K`, `L` for historical reasons.

Answer (score 40):

You could prove to yourself that there is no other difference by trying to define a function in a struct.  I remember even my college professor who was teaching about structs and classes in C++ was surprised to learn this (after being corrected by a student).  I believe it, though.  It was kind of amusing.  The professor kept saying what the differences were and the student kept saying "actually you can do that in a struct too".  Finally the prof. asked "OK, what is the difference" and the student informed him that the only difference was the default accessibility of members.

A quick Google search suggests that POD stands for "Plain Old Data".

Comment: A bad time for that teacher, and no doubt :)

Comment: That teacher was trying to explore/learned the difference between struct and class in C not C++ because in C we can't add functions in struct.

Comment: C doesnt even have classes :P people just think structs in C++ can't have methods because they think of C++ as a superset of C which leads to the incorrect assumption that C++ structs are the same as C structs.

Answer (score 8):

POD classes are Plain-Old data classes that have only data members and nothing else. There are a few questions on stackoverflow about the same. Find one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c).

Also, you can have functions as members of structs in C++ but not in C. You need to have pointers to functions as members in structs in C.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, POD means *plain old data*. That usually refers to `structs` *without* any methods because these types are then used to structure multiple data that belong together.

As for structs not having methods: I have seen more than once that a struct had methods, and I don't feel that this would be unnatural.

Answer (score 2):

1) It is the only difference in C++.

2) POD: [plain old data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) Other classes -> not POD