# Structures vs objects C++

Tags: c++, class, object, data-structures, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between struct and class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)
>   [C++ - struct vs. class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791883/c-struct-vs-class)

How are structures different from objects and classes in C++? Is there any performance benefit to using objects or structures?

Comment: What exactly are those “objects” you're talking about?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Structures and classes are identical; the language standard uses the term "class" to refer to both. The only difference between defining a class using the `struct` or the `class` keyword is the default accessibility of members and base classes; there is no difference in their runtime behaviour or performance.

An "object" is a run-time instance of a type. In C++, the term is used for instances of any type, including classes and fundamental types.

Answer (score 0):

main thing is by default variables are private in a class and by default they are public in structures.  also you can google this and find a million and one topics on this. for example http://blog.stevedoria.net/20050913/differences-between-cpp-classes-and-structs