# Converting struct in C++ to Ruby

Tags: c++, ruby, module, struct

I'm trying to convert this code:

```
#pragma once
#include "thread.h"
#include <vector>

struct Process {
  enum Type {
    SYSTEM,
    USER
  };

  // process ID
  int pid;

  // process type
  Type type;

  // threads belonging to this process
  std::vector<Thread*> threads;

  // constructor
  Process(int pid, Type type) : pid(pid), type(type) {}
};
```

into Ruby, but I can't figure it out. I've tried using a module, but found out you can't really have constructors in a Module. I don't really understand the ruby struct class either. If somebody could either explain these or help me convert it, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be worth a look:

[C++ - struct vs. class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791883/c-struct-vs-class)

Your struct is what most languages (including Ruby) would call a class (not a C style struct):

```
class Process
  def initialize(pid, type)
    @type = type
    @pid = pid
    @threads = []
  end
  attr_accessor :type, :pid, :threads
end
```

You need the `attr_accessor` to make the members public (this being the default behavior of structs in C++).

Comment: ok that is what I thought, but it just didn't seem right to be using a class as a struct. I didn't realize that they didn't compare the same way. I also don't understand why I got downvoted, maybe it's because my question was too specific?