# In C++, is a struct also a class?

Tags: c++, class, struct, taxonomy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++ Struct vs Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750270/c-c-struct-vs-class)

I know the technical differences between a struct and a class; and of course *that question* has been asked before.

Object-oriented programming relates objects and classes. In C++ *taxonomy*, is a struct also a class?

Comment: I want to mark this duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c, but actually that question and its answers don't come right out and say that a class defined with `struct` is just as much a class as a class defined with `class` is. In that sense, the question "what are the differences between a struct and a class" is already wrong-headed, it implies there are two kinds of types. It should be "what are the differences between keyword struct and keyword class", since in C++ there isn't really any such thing as "a struct".

Comment: I read both questions prior to asking, and believe it is not a duplicate; hopefully a simple, *specific*, and useful question; for me at least. This is a question of *taxonomy*. *Is* a C++ "struct", also a "class"? Thanks.

Comment: This is not an *exact* duplicate of either [C/C++ Struct vs Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750270/c-c-struct-vs-class) or [What are the differences between struct and class in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c).

Comment: @user643722: in that case the answer you want is 9/4: "A *structure* is a class...". Any further information about the differences is waffle from your POV. Beware using this definition strictly, though. I think the word "structure" is used inadvisedly in (for example) 17.1.8, I'm not sure I believe the standard really intends to say that it's undefined behavior for the `traits` template argument to be defined with `class`. Also when the standard mentions "data structures" it usually means classes, not structures in this sense.

Comment: There is also a difference when predeclaring the class/struct: If a struct is defined as `struct A { ... };`, then when it is predeclared, it needs to be predeclared as `struct A;`, also not `class A;`.
Some compilers (e.g. MSVC) distinguish use different name mangling for `class` or `struct` members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taxonomically, yes. Other than their different default access specifiers, they are exactly the same *in C++*.

- All members and attributes of a
  `struct` are `public` by default.
- All members and attributes of a
  `class` are `private` by default.

Comment: You say, essentially, yes. Can I have a definitive yes? :) ( I do know the technical differences. )

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's a full-blown class - `struct` keyword is a syntactic sugar that makes all members publicly accessible by default, while they are private by default in a `class`.

Comment: +1. The syntax is still there, mainly, to allow full compatibility with plain C.

Comment: Thanks sharptooth. I know these differences. I guess you're instinct is that through being so similar, a struct is also a class. Is that also the position taken in the C++ standard? One reason I ask is that I've seen comments correcting an author's reference to a struct as a class.

Comment: Is there a difference regarding the way both occupy memory?

Comment: @Salaman: No. They are the same. This is not C#.

Comment: @user643722 - This is mostly a historical accident. Once upon a time, classes were added to C, creating the language "C with classes". This language eventually evolved into what we now know as C++. Somewhere along the way, someone one day asked "Why can't we have member functions in a struct?". And the reply was "No reason." So, there we are.

Comment: @Bo: Yes, I have heard that old saw many times. I am curious as to whether, *now*, regarding C++, a struct *is* (also) a class.

Comment: @user643722 - That was for the history lesson, why we have both class and struct. Right now a struct is like a class, only with public access and public inheritance as defaults.

Comment: @Bo: Thanks. So you would answer, no?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The ONLY difference is that by default in a `class` everything is private, and in a `struct`, by default everything is public. The difference, in that sense is purely syntactical.

Comment: And by being a purely syntactical difference, does that mean a struct is also a class?

Comment: or in other words, do 'class' and 'struct' have separate namespaces? Can `class foo` and `struct foo` both exist at the same time?

Comment: @Alnitak: Try it. Your compiler will complain of a redefinition of `struct foo` (or `class foo`, whichever you define first).

Comment: @Alnitak: No, this a question of taxonomy.

Comment: indeed - having a shared namespace is further evidence of their shared taxonomy.

Comment: @Alnitak: Agreed. It doesn't seem as if anyone is *absolutely* certain about this, well apart from maybe Johnsyweb.

Answer (score 3):

1. The member's of a struct are public by default
2. The default inheritance for a class is private while for a struct it is public

Comment: In my question I did mention that I knew the technical differences.