# Can we define a structure on type?

Tags: c++, class, types, struct

So I am looking on question about struct vs class difference... And I do not get one thing - can we define a structure on type? like tiped class... If yes please provide some samples.

Comment: Classes and structures *are* types as far as I know... Can you clarify what you mean by *typed class*? Would you perchance be referring to templates?

Comment: What does to "define structure on type" mean? If you can give an example of "tiped class" it might be easier to answer. PS. I didn't down-vote.

Comment: As for "struc vs class difference", the probably most concise definition comes from Mr. Stroustrup himself: `struct - class with members public by default`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++ Struct vs Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750270/c-c-struct-vs-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean, Can you use a struct much like you would use a class? the answer is yes. In C++ the only difference is the defaults for visibility. Members of a class default to private; members of a struct default to public. If you create a class and make all the members public, it's pretty much the same as a struct. I understand that compilers vary on whether a struct can inherit from a class and vice versa.

Frankly, I think struct's exist in C++ mainly for upward compatibility from C. Or to put it another way, class's only exist because that's the new name for the same idea.

Comment: Re: "I understand that compilers vary on whether a struct can inherit from a class and vice versa" - they certainly shouldn't. Apart from the default accessibility, classes and structs are the same thing, and can be used interchangeably.

Comment: But most programmers still use `struct` for POD and `class` for OO/datahiding stuff. The difference is small from the POV of the compiler, but is a strong hint to human readers of the code.

Comment: Technically, `struct`s don't exist; both the keyword `struct` and the keyword `class` define a class type.  In practice, programmers use one or the other keyword depending on local coding conventions.

Comment: @larsmans: Good point. I tend to just use class in my C++ programs, but it's not a bad idea from a "self documentation" point of view. Rather in the same category of naming conventions that say to begin class names with an upper case letter but instance names with lower case. Of course it makes no difference to the compiler, but it improves readability.