# Can someone explain this C++ syntax?

Tags: c++

I'm going through someone else's code and came across the following syntax:

```
typedef struct abc {

   abc() : member(0){}

   unsigned int member

}
```

It seems like a class with member variable and a constructor, except it is declared struct. I have two questions here.

1. Is this syntax supported in C?
2. What would be a reason to use structs over classes?

Thanks a lot in advance.

PS: how do I format the code?

Comment: I formatted the code for you by indenting 4 spaces. You can highlight the code and press the `{}` icon above the editing field. You need to leave a blank line before and after the code. Similar thing goes for the numbered list.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750270/c-c-struct-vs-class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not valid C.

In C++, `struct` and `class` are essentially synonyms.  The only difference is that members and inheritance are `public` by default in a `struct`, and `private` by default in a `class`.

There are no hard guidelines on whether to choose `struct` or `class`.  However, you'll often find people using `struct` only for simple C-like *plain old data* structures ("PODs").

Comment: The same goes for inheritance.

Comment: I often use struct when building functors.

Answer (score 3):

This is most assuredly just C++. `struct` and `class` are identical in C++, except for defaulting to public instead of private for inheritance and class contents.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, struct and class are essentially the same thing, except that for a struct members are public by default.  So just read it as you would a class.

Answer (score 0):

`abc()` is a constructor of class `abc`, `member` is a internal variable, constructor `abc` defaults set `member` as 0.

Answer (score 0):

1. The syntax is supported. The constructor initializes `member` to `0` and does nothing else.
2. `struct` has a default access of `public`.

Answer (score 0):

This is C++ code, however using `typedef struct` (that comes from C) in C++ code is awful. There is difference between C and C++ and in C++ you don't need to `typedef` structs. `struct MyStruct` is sufficient declaration if you want to refer your struct via `MyStruct myStruct;`. Mixing C with C++ is bad.