# How good is "new/delete" on struct in place of "malloc/free", in C++?

Tags: c++, class, struct

Many a times, I have seen in C++ code pointers allocations for structs as;

```
struct Current{
int amp;
};

Current *cur = new Current();
```

However, "Current" is a structure and not class here, but is supported in C++. How good is this to be used in place of C-type allocation, as below:

```
Current *cur = (Current*) malloc (sizeof(Current));
```

What is the underlying concept behind this? One known to me is, that the "structs" are considered as "classes" in C++.

Concept of struct-VS-class in C++ is known. Query is majorly about the specific use case, as both are permissible, but which should be preferred over, and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++ Struct vs Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750270/c-c-struct-vs-class)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between struct and class in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)

Comment: In C++, using new/delete is recommended over using malloc()/free(), even for structs (which are the same as classes except that member variables are public by default)

Comment: struct/class, same thing really. Anyway, why do you use dynamic allocation in the first place? Are you sure you need it? Usually people who are new to C++ like to use the `new` keyword for no reason. That is why it is called `new`. It is short for `newbie`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, a `struct` is the same as a `class`, except that it has default `public` members, as well as default `public` inheritance.

As for the use of `malloc`, although it is possible to use it, it is as you say a `C`-type allocation, and shouldn't be used for `C++`. If you must, you would use `malloc/free` the same way for a struct as for a class.

However, the correct `C++` way is to use `new` and `delete`, which are also used the same for a `struct` as for a `class`.

---

If you're curious as to *why* `new/delete` should be used instead of  `malloc/free`, I refer you to this Q/A: [In what cases do I use malloc vs new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new)

---

As far as the use of parenthesis, i.e.:

```
Current *cur = new Current();
//vs.
Current *cur = new Current;
```

See this: [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

I just did myself, and learned something new.

Comment: New also invokes constructor in contrary to malloc

Comment: The parentheses actually make a difference in this case.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on why there is nothing wrong the parens @LightningRacisinObrit ? It seems you could be right. But I'm unsure as to why this is.

Comment: `new Current()` will initialize `amp` to 0, while `new Current` will not. The parentheses are actually better.

Comment: @swalog It is wrong to say they should not be used. In this case, using them results in zero-initialization of `amp`. Without them, `amp` is left uninitialized.

Comment: thanks @swalog. I have now clear understanding, to the 4 related information : new with and without "()" operator, when and why to use delete/free and new/malloc and what is POD. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

You've misunderstood `struct`s.

> However, "Current" is a structure and not class here, but is supported in C++

Wrong. `Current` *is* a class. It would also be a class if you'd declared it with the keyword `class` instead of the keyword `struct`.

The keyword `struct` is provided for backward compatibility, and using it changes some visibility defaults in the definition syntax. But, otherwise, you are still just defining a class.

Certainly there is nothing magical about classes defined with `struct` that means you should go back to archaic C-style allocations.