# gsoap how to generate structure instead of a class for complex type

Tags: c++, gsoap, complextype

I have a complex type that is not optional but wsdl2h is always generating a class for it instead of structure. I want minimum usage of pointers in my C++ webservice.

sample wsdl

```
 <xsd:complexType name="TestInformation">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="name" type="tns:name" minOccurs="1"
            nillable="false" />
          <xsd:element name="address" type="tns:address"
            minOccurs="1" nillable="false" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="TestRequest">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="test" type="tns:TestInformation"
            minOccurs="1" nillable="false" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

generated header file:

```
class TestInformation
{ public:

    ns2__name            name         1;      ///< Required element.

    ns2__address         address      1;      ///< Required element.

    struct soap          *soap                          ;
};
```

I want     class TestInformation to struct TestInformation & not pointer of it in stubs.

Comment: I think you shoud read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750270/c-c-struct-vs-class

Comment: I just want to avoid generation of objects on heap ...generating structs wud help me... generating C style code do so but I want structs generation in C++ code.