# Interchanging class & struct keyword in C++

Tags: c++, injected-class-name

I was reading about one of the strange C++ feature called **Injected class name** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549652/c-why-is-there-injected-class-name).

I tried following simple program

```
#include <iostream>
class test
{
    int s{3};
    public:
    int get_s()
    { return s; }
};
int main() {
    class test::test s;  // struct test::test s; also allowed. Why???
    std::cout<<s.get_s();
}
```

If I replace **class** keyword with **struct** in first line of main() program still compiles & runs fine. See live demo [here](http://ideone.com/k9OHK9). Why? Shouldn't I get compiler error? Why it compiles fine?

Comment: What compiler error do you expect?

Comment: actually an interesting question, but unfortunately the title is misleading, your actual question has nothing to do with "injected class names".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the relevant verse is in 7.1.6.3/3 (highlighting mine, quoted here from a draft of the C++17 Standard):

> Thus, in any *elaborated-type-specifier*, the `enum` keyword shall be used to refer to an enumeration (7.2), the `union` *class-key* shall be used to refer to a union (Clause 9), and **either the `class` or `struct` *class-key* shall be used to refer to a class (Clause 9) declared using the `class` or `struct` *class-key***.

So either keyword can be used to stipulate the scope within which the injected class name exists, irrespective of which was used to declare/define `test`.

Answer (score 2):

struct and class are almost identical in C++. The only difference is, that members of structs are public by default while member of classes are private by default.

see complete answer here: [C/C++ Struct vs Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750270/c-c-struct-vs-class)

Answer (score 0):

`class test s;`
or
`struct test s;` works too.

Classes and structs in C++ are virtually the same thing.

The difference is:

```
struct A{
};
```

is like

```
class A{
public:
};
```

and

```
class B{
};
```

is like

```
struct B{
private:
};
```

Allowing you to use the `struct` prefix is for C compatibility and I guess it extends to `class` because "why not?".

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, maybe I have misunderstood your post but there is no big differences between class and struct in C++.
The main differences that I know is that by default, a struct have all field public.

There is a post talking about differences between struct and class :
[What are the differences between struct and class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)