# Difference between struct node *next and node *next?

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, nodes

I saw this piece of code :

```
 struct node {
   int data;
   struct node* next;
 };
```

I also saw this piece of code:

```
struct node {
  int data;
  node* next;
};
```

What are the differences, and advantages/disadvantages between the two?

Comment: The first version is valid in both C and C++, while the second is only valid in C++.

Comment: @DeiDei: The 2nd version can be made to work in C with a little `typedef` or a forward declaration

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750270/c-c-struct-vs-class

Comment: No appreciable difference. Advantage: Less typing in the `struct`-less version.

Comment: Thanks for the responses :)