# Why would we like to use “class” instead of using “structure” in CPP? Explain with examples

Tags: c++, oop

Why would we like to use “class” instead of using “structure” in CPP? Explain with
examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750270/c-c-struct-vs-class

Answer (score 0):

Literally In C++ Basically All The Members Of A Class Are Private By Default And In Strut The Members Are Public That's The Difference.And For Your Question It's Up to The Programmer That What Kind Of Project Is He Working.