# What is a non-member of a struct?

Tags: c++, struct

In an assignment, I was asked to take a member function from a struct and make it a non-member of that struct, but I don't know what that means, and can't seem to get an answer. I certainly don't want it done for me, so is there any way someone can explain what they're asking of me, so I can figure the rest out?

Comment: I think this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572665/c-structs-with-member-functions-vs-classes-with-public-variables) could be a good starting point

Comment: "non-member" means that it is not a member of any struct. It doesn't have any assocation with a particular struct type

Answer (score 3):

A non-member function `f` that accepts a parameter of type `T&` named `t`, e.g. `void f(T& t)`, is very similar to a member function `void T::f()`, just that `*this` is replaced by `t`. The big difference is that it cannot access the `private` members of the type, but by default that's an *advantage* because it enhances encapsulation

(Unless it happens to be a `friend`, of course. From an encapsulation point of view, non-member `friend` functions are much more similar to member functions than to non-member, non-`friend` functions.)

Comment: It can, if it is a friend. Happens often with stream operators.