# Abstract/Base struct in C++?

Tags: c++, class, struct, abstract-class, structure

I'm making a chess game and I would like to have an array of pieces.

If I'm correct, in Java you can have an abstract `Piece` class and have `King` or `Queen` extend that class.  If I were to make an array of `Piece`s I could place a `King` piece somewhere in that array and a `Queen` piece at another spot because both `King` and `Queen` extend `Piece`.

Is there any way to do that with structures in C++?

Comment: structures are generally for c, c++ gives you classes and OOP so i would stick to that since you are new to c/c++.

Comment: @L7ColWinters: Why are structures not OOP? Why should you use classes instead?

Comment: @L7ColWinters: That's a weird statement. `struct` and `class` are almost identical.

Comment: There's a good discussion about them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585/when-should-you-use-a-class-vs-a-struct-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can create an [abstract base class](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/abcs.html) in C++. Simply set one or more of the methods to be pure virtual:

```
class Piece {
    public:
        Piece ();
        virtual ~Piece ();
        virtual void SomeMethod () = 0;  // This method is not implemented in the base class, making it a pure virtual method. Subclasses must implement it
 };
```

You can then create sub-classes that implement the pure virtual methods

```
class King : public Piece {
    // ... the rest of the class definition
    virtual void SomeMethod (); // You need to actually implement this
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simulate an **[Abstract class](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/abcs.html)** in C++ by adding a pure virtual function to an class.

In c++ You can do everything with structures which you can on classes .
A structure in C++ only differs from an class in terms of default access specification for members and during Inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Sure.

```
class AbstractPiece
{
public:
virtual void aFunction()=0; //this makes AbstractPiece an abstract class.
virtual ~AbstractPiece();
};

class King : public AbstractPiece
{
public:
virtual void aFunction(); //this is the one that would get called
virtual ~King();
};
```

And then, later,

```
AbstractPiece* array[size];
```

and

```
array[index] = new King();
```

Comment: You are missing a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inheritance in C++ in almost the same way as you do in Java. C++ has both classes and structures, and in this case you can use either.

Abstract classes in C++ are just classes with pure virtual methods in them. These are methods without a method definition.

Your solution might look something like this:

```
class Piece {
public:
   virtual ~Piece ();
   virtual void move() = 0; //this is a pure virtual function, making this an abstract class.
};

class King : public Piece {
public:
   void move() {};
};

class Queen : public Piece {
public:
  void move() {};
};

....

Piece *myPieces[2] = new Piece*[2];
myPieces[0] = new King();
myPieces[1] = new Queen();
```

Comment: that's not valid C++ class syntax. You don't prepend access specifiers in front of the `class` keyword. You'll also have potential splicing issue by assigning k and q to myPieces like that.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code a bit. What do you mean by splicing issue?

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the code again. Hopefully this looks better.

Comment: @VictorT. I think you mean slicing, not splicing

Comment: @PeterWood yes that's what I meant, thanks for the correction :P

Comment: In fact, pure virtual methods *can* be defined, even though this is not the most common scenario.

Comment: You are missing a virtual destructor.

Comment: lol. Edited again. I really hope that's everything this time. :P I forgot a lot more C++ than I thought

Answer (score 1):

**In c++ you can use abstract classes or structures:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/construct.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct piece
{
    virtual ~piece() {};
    virtual void dosomething() = 0;
};

struct king : piece
{
    ~king() { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; }
    void dosomething() { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; }
};

struct queen : piece
{
    ~queen() { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; }
    void dosomething() { cout <<  __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; }
};

struct pawn : piece
{
    ~pawn() { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; }
    void dosomething() { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; }
};
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::vector< piece * > pieces_t;
    pieces_t pieces;
    pieces.push_back(new queen());
    pieces.push_back(new king());
    pieces.push_back(new pawn());
    pieces.push_back(new pawn());
    pieces.push_back(new pawn());
    pieces.push_back(new pawn());

    // calling dosomething()
    std::for_each(pieces.begin(), pieces.end(), 
          boost::lambda::bind(&piece::dosomething, boost::lambda::_1));

    // destructing
    std::for_each(pieces.begin(), pieces.end(), 
          boost::lambda::bind(boost::lambda::delete_ptr(), boost::lambda::_1));
}
```

Output:

```
virtual void queen::dosomething()
virtual void king::dosomething()
virtual void pawn::dosomething()
virtual void pawn::dosomething()
virtual void pawn::dosomething()
virtual void pawn::dosomething()
virtual queen::~queen()
virtual king::~king()
virtual pawn::~pawn()
virtual pawn::~pawn()
virtual pawn::~pawn()
virtual pawn::~pawn()
```

Comment: This is an incredibly complex answer to a very simple question! Did you really need to introduce `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, boost, lambdas, standard algorithms, etc.?

Comment: @LucTouraille I'm used to using `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` because it shows the class name and parameter types/return values. This way it's easy to see what gets called. As for the rest, I didn't really want to spend more time for a simple answer so I used what first came to my mind - of course I could spend more time typing and make the answer lengthier ....

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to avoid using pointers as you have to remember to clean them up.

This design uses the strategy pattern. The interface is `PieceType`, which allows you to display valid positions on a board, or show the initial positions on the board. I'm sure there's more you would want each strategy to be able to do:

```
class Board;

class PieceType
{
public:
    virtual showValidMoves(Board& board) const = 0;
    virtual showInitialPosition(Board& board) const = 0;
    // ...  
};

class Pawn : public PieceType
{
public:
    virtual showValidMoves(Board& board) const;
    virtual showInitialPosition(Board& board) const;
    // ...
};

class Rook : public PieceType
{
    // ...
};
//...
```

We only need one of each `PieceType`, and as that type is shared across chessmen, it can also be const:

```
const Pawn PAWN;
const Rook ROOK;
const Knight KNIGHT;
```

We use these strategies to initialise the Chessmen we keep in a vector:

```
class ChessMan
{
public:
    enum Colour {Black, White};

    ChessMan(const Colour& colour, PieceType& pieceType);

    void showValidMoves(Board& board);
    void showInitialPosition(Board& board);
private:
    Colour m_colour;
    PieceType& m_pieceType;
};
```

I'll wrap up the code for adding a `ChessMan` to a vector in its own function:

```
void add(vector<ChessMan>& chessmen,
         const ChessMan::Colour& colour,
         const PieceType& pieceType,
         const unsigned int amount)
{
    chessmen.insert(chessmen.end(), ChessMan(colour, pieceType), amount);
}

void main()
{
    using std::vector;

    vector<ChessMan> chessmen;
    add(chessmen, 16, ChessMan::Black, PAWN);
    add(chessmen, 2, ChessMan::Black, ROOK);
    add(chessmen, 2, ChessMan::Black, KNIGHT);
    //...
}
```

Bonne chance!

Comment: The question is about abstract base classes, not about the best design for a chess game. Even though your answer could interest the original poster, it does not address the question at all.

Comment: @LucTouraille I think it's important to use containers for homogeneous data. The heterogeneous behaviour is better stored elsewhere. So I've put the pointers to the abstract class inside the homogeneous objects. I think it's a good principle. I'm sorry if the example was too long, or looked like I was providing a whole solution. You're free to edit it and make it better.