# When to use struct over class in c++

Tags: c++, oop, class, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should you use a class vs a struct in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585/when-should-you-use-a-class-vs-a-struct-in-c)

When, if ever, should one use a STRUCT declaration rather than a CLASS declaration when writing a program using C++?

1. Never !! ?
2. Any thing...whichever makes one feel better?

Comment: Arghhhh... I hate when my name is put next to a vote to close reason which I didn't select.

Comment: Please read the details of struct and class here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585/when-should-you-use-a-class-vs-a-struct-in-c/47168608#47168608 . Basically I use structs for data structures where the members can take any value, it's easier that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference between the two is that by default `struct` are public while `class` members are private.

My rule is to use `struct` when I mean a clump of related data without any special semantics on reading/writing them. Use `class` when I intend to wrap the data in richer semantics (read methods) that are more meaningful, provide any needed protection, or implement something more abstract.

Answer (score 6):

Besides the default access level, a `struct` and a `class` are **completely equivalent**.

I find that the difference is mostly in the mind of a programmer - by convention, we typically use `struct`s to put together small objects, without complex functionality - for example, a `Point` with just 3 members - the coordinates. POD-types.

On the other hand, we typically use `class`es to encompass somewhat bigger objects, with complex functionality and fairly large interface.

For example:

```
struct Point { 
   int x,y,z; 
};

class Shape{
   std::vector<Point> corners;
public:
   Shape(const std::vector<Point> corners);
   double getVolume();
   double getArea();
   bool   isConvex();
   //etc.
};
```