# Do these members have unspecified ordering?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03

A colleague told me that, in the following type, all members have unspecified ordering in memory (relative to one another).

I doubt this, because they all have the same access level.

Who is correct?

```
struct foo { public: int x; public: int y; public: int z; };
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your colleague is correct for C++03:

> `[C++03: 9.2/12]:` Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class declared **without an intervening access-specifier** are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of nonstatic data members separated by an access-specifier is unspecified (11.1). *[..]*

But you are correct for C++11:

> `[C++11: 9.2/14]:` Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class **with the same access control** (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspecified (11). *[..]*

(Spot the difference.)