# How to use variable type Struct inside class?

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have to build a videogame with SDL for my end year proyect. However I'm somewhat lost about how and when to use classes.

T tried to include a variable type struct inside a class but I can't manage to do it, maybe Position should be a class instead of a struct? Here's my code:

```
struct Position{
    int x,y;
};

class Object{
    private:
        Position pos;
        Position speed;
        int tipe;
    public:
        Objeto(int,int);
        Objeto();
        ~Objeto(); // DESTROY
};
```

When I try to do this I get error: `'class Object' has no member named 'x'` How can I include the struct in the object?

Comment: Already you have included (used) `Position` in `Objeto`. What's the problem?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585/when-should-you-use-a-class-vs-a-struct-in-c

Comment: Why the downvote? I added the error log to the question...

Comment: Objeto.pos.x, Objeto.pos.y

Comment: @Liso22 That code on its own would not produce that error. There actually nothing wrong with the code you have posted. You should also show the source code which produces the error.

Comment: @Liso22 you should update your question with the code that the error actually occurs on, so that the actual problem is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your error, I think you are trying to use

```
Objeto.x
```

instead of

```
Objeto.pos.x
```

Comment: thanks, it was actually this. I wrote it correctly when I typed the question