# Is it legal to use a different class-key in a declaration and the definition of a class-name?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, forward-declaration

Does the standard (as of C++20) explicitly or implicitly allow using a different *class-key* when (forward-)declaring a *class-name* than when defining it?
For the purpose of this question *class-key* shall be limited to `class` or `struct`, excluding `union`.

In other words, is this legal:

```
struct C;
class C{};
class S;
struct S{};
```

An answer should explicitly refer to the C++20 standard (or a suitable draft).

---

I couldn't find anything in the entire [[class]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class) section.

The only indication I could find is in [[decl.type.elab.6]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab#6) which first states:

> The class-key or enum keyword present in the elaborated-type-specifier shall agree in kind with the declaration to which the name in the elaborated-type-specifier refers.

But to me it is unclear what *kind* means in this context. I suppose `enum` and `struct` are different kinds but are `struct` and `class` different kinds? I don't know. Anyway after some unrelated points about friends it goes on to say:

> Thus, in any elaborated-type-specifier, the enum keyword shall be used
> to refer to an enumeration ([dcl.enum]), the union class-key shall be
> used to refer to a union ([class.union]), and *either the class or
> struct class-key shall be used to refer to a non-union class*
> ([class.pre]).

(emph added)

This sort of sounds as if `struct` and `class` were interchangeable, but I'm not sure about it.

---

According to code explorer it appears to be [generally accepted by compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/zodzTds9c).

---

### Non-Duplicates

- I do not believe [Mixing class and struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4866425/430766) answers the question. Due to its age, it talks about a different version of the standard. Also, the one answer that actually quotes the standard does not convince: The quoted paragraph has a lot of ambiguity and does not address the question asked here.
- [Forward declaration as struct vs class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40738351/430766) has no answers actually bothering to prove their assertions by citation.
- [Changing struct to class (and other type changes) and ABI/code generation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23940237/430766) Asks about two *definitions* with different class-keys. Its answer does not apply here.

Comment: Probably related/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40738351/417197

Comment: @André Ah yes. I searched previously to asking but didn't find anything. However, the related question has no answers that include standardese.

Comment: Hence the comment, instead of a close vote. I've found a better one:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/4866425/417197

Comment: @justANewbstandswithUkraine No it doesn't as it refers to an unspecified version of the standard but one that is necessarily older than C++20 as per the date it was posted. Furthermore I do not believe any of the answers actually answers the question posed here.

Comment: _An answer should explicitly refer to the C++20 standard_ Unless you explain why you expect change in C++20, this is an invalid requirement. At least, for complaining about dups. C++ is known to maintain backward compatibility.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I care about C++20. If it is unchanged then it should still be present in C++20. However, answers that refer to old standards contain references that simply do not exist anymore, so I cannot verify that this behaviour is unchanged in C++20. I find it quite frankly presumptuous for you to dictate what is and isn't a valid requirement for a question that *I have*.

Comment: In C++20, look in Section 9.2.8.3, para 1.    The wording is a bit more complicated than in previous standards (consistent with the approach of indulging language lawyers in the last few years).  But the equivalence of declarations `struct S;` and `class S;` and being able to follow that up with either (not both) `struct S {...};` or `class S{...};` has been part of C++ since the ARM was written, so it's not likely to change - changing that equivalence would break a lot of real-world code, retaining it does not.

Comment: @Peter Thanks. I already stumbled upon [dcl.type.elab](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.type.elab) but I'm not sure which phrase you are referring to. I don't see where paragraph 1 makes a point about how to interchange class-key keywords.

Comment: The example under that verse uses both `struct S` and `class S`.

Comment: @duck Maybe this is a bit nitpicky, but Examples are non-authoritative as far as I know.

Comment: _Examples are non-authoritative as far as I know_ The authoritative part is above the Example. Examples are intended to resolve doubts like your _This sort of sounds as if struct and class were interchangeable, but I'm not sure about it_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard explains this in [9.2.8.3.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.type.elab#3) and clarifies it in the example, as Peter already pointed out in a comment to your question:

> [...] either the `class` or `struct` *class-key* shall be used to refer to a non-union class
> [...]
>
> ```cpp
> struct S { } s;
> class S* p = &s;    // OK
> ```

The compilers agree, as can be seen by the warning clang generates:

> warning: 'C' defined as a struct here but previously declared as a class; this is valid, but may result in linker errors under the Microsoft C++ ABI [-Wmismatched-tags]

GCC has a [faq entry](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#Wmismatched-tags):

> Because it is not a bug, hence the warning is just noise. This is a
> dumb warning that only exists because the MS compiler has a bug that
> treats struct and class differently in mangled names. GCC (and Clang)
> correctly implement the C++ standard which says it doesn't matter.

Comment: That FAQ entry is just gold. But it also confirms this interpretation of the standard.