# unordered_map hash function return

Tags: c++, struct, set, unordered-map, hash-function

I'd like to have an `unordered_map` with a `struct`, that I'd like to use as the key, of multiple `std::set< std::string >`.

I see that a custom hash function [is required](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and that a string can have [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) applied; however, I cannot determine what should be returned to satisfy the purpose of the hash function of these sets for an unordered_map.

How should a custom hash function return?

Comment: The description of the data structure you want is a bit vague. To clearify, you want a `std::unordered_map<myStruct>` where `myStruct` is a custom *class* with multiple `std::set<std::string>` members? And you need advice on how to create a *hash function* for `myStruct`?

Comment: @Snps Yes, but I was creating `myStruct` as a `struct` rather than `class`, yet I'll take anything I can get.  Thank you for looking!

Comment: In C++ `struct` means **class** with default visibility set to *public*.

Comment: There is no *real* difference between `struct` and `class` ;)

Comment: Thanks guys!  I was just following this until I found a need to do otherwise  http://stackoverflow.com/a/54596/1382306  I'm guessing that's now?  ;))

Comment: Well, simply use `struct` if everything is going to be public anyway, i.e. you don't implement the principle of *data hiding*. (But you can change it if you decide to do so.) -- That doesn't change your question though :)

Comment: @Gracchus: A `std::unordered_map` holds key-value pairs. Is your struct the __key__ or the __value__? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: `struct` defines a class, simple as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be a better alternative to [Snps' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24814826/445976). This implements a specialization of `std::hash` for a user-defined type and it hashes the struct without creating temporary strings.

I've copied two functions from Boost, `hash_combine` and `hash_range`, to compute a single hash value from two containers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>

// user-defined type
struct myStruct {
    std::set<std::string> s1;
    std::set<std::string> s2;

    bool operator==(const myStruct &other) const {
        return (s1 == other.s1) && (s2 == other.s2);
    }
};

// hash helper functions plagiarized from Boost
template <typename T>
void hash_combine(size_t &seed, const T &v)
{
    using std::hash;
    seed ^= hash<T>()(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
}

template <typename It>
void hash_range(size_t &seed, It first, It last)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        hash_combine(seed, *first);
    }
}

// std::hash specialization
namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<myStruct> {
        size_t operator()(const myStruct &key) const {
            size_t seed = 0;
            hash_range(seed, key.s1.begin(), key.s1.end());
            hash_range(seed, key.s2.begin(), key.s2.end());
            return seed;
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<myStruct, int> myMap;

    myStruct ms1{ { "apple", "pear", "orange" }, { "red", "green", "blue" } };
    myStruct ms2{ { "pear", "apple", "orange" }, { "red", "green", "blue" } };
    myStruct ms3{ { "apple", "banana", "orange" }, { "red", "green", "blue" } };

    myMap[ms1] = 1;
    myMap[ms2] = 2;
    myMap[ms3] = 3;

    std::cout << myMap.size() << '\n'; // output: 2
}
```

Comment: Thank you Blastfurnace!  Two questions: could you detail the last line of `hash_combine`, and why should `myMap.size()` output `2`?  Shouldn't it be '3'?  It's not a criticism.  It comes from inexperience.  Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @Gracchus: The `hash_combine` function is from the [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html) and is used to incrementally build a hash from different values. The method and numeric constants were derived by someone much smarter than I to produce a uniform result. The output is 2 because `ms1` and `ms2` contain identical `std::set` values and therefore produce the same hash. A `std::unordered_map` only holds unique keys so the second insertion fails because it would be a duplicate key. A `std::unordered_multimap` allows duplicate keys.

Comment: As for the first answer: wow!  For the second: facepalm duh.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @Gracchus "facepalm duh", I did put in an effort in order to help you. Is the final outcome/best answer all that matters? :)

Comment: @Snps: It was your answer that motivated me to create this answer and I learned things in the process. I felt there had to be a better way without all the string concatenation. I thank you!

Comment: @Snps I upvoted your answer, and I think it's very good, but I think that stack wants/demands "the ultimate correct answer", so if one comes along with a "perfect" `hash_combine`, that will get the check.  I absolutely do ***NOT*** agree with downvoter.  Your answer may not be "most correct", but it is not bad by any means...in my inexperienced opinion.

Comment: @Gracchus I agree in that this answer deserves the accept more than mine, it's better, I just reacted on the "facepalm duh"-comment which I (mis?)interpreted as discredit to my answer.

Comment: @Snps Oh jeez, no!  I was talking about Blastfurnace's responses to my two questions in the comment above.  I should've known that `ms1 == ms2`.  :/

Comment: @Gracchus Ah just a misunderstanding then! Happy coding! :)

Comment: @Snps You too!  And thank you for taking the time to produce such a thorough answer!

Comment: This is a good answer. It's true `boost::hash_combine` isn't ideal (or, even, good in many situations). Combining hashes is not an easy problem; you might find the paper 'Types don't know #' by @HowardHinnant to be helpful: http://isocpp.org/blog/2014/05/n3980

Comment: @NikBougalis: Thanks for the link, that was an interesting read.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements of `std::hash` is as follows: (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)

*The hash template defines a function object that implements a hash function. Instances of this function object satisfy Hash. In particular, they define an **operator()** that:*

1. *Accepts a single parameter of type `Key`.*
2. *Returns a value of type `size_t` that represents the hash value of the parameter.*
3. *Does not throw exceptions when called.*
4. *For two parameters `k1` and `k2` that are equal, `std::hash<Key>()(k1) == std::hash<Key>()(k2)`.*
5. *For two different parameters `k1` and `k2` that are not equal, the probability that `std::hash<Key>()(k1) == std::hash<Key>()(k2)` should be very small, approaching `1.0 / std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`.*

*The hash template is both **CopyConstructible** and **Destructible**.*

So what you need is basically a function that returns a `std::size_t` that is unique for every `myStruct` object and that returns the same value for objects that are considered equivalent.

### Edit: The following may not be the most robust way to generate the hash, but it will serve as a basic example of how it can be done.

One way to do it is to use the standard specialization for `std::hash<std::string>` by concatenating all the strings in each `std::set` member using a *separator sequence* and then concatenating all the resulting merged strings into one and returning the hash value using the standard hash function.

The merged "super"-string will be unique for each `myStruct` object if the member `std::set`s differ, and still same when the members don't differ as `std::set` is an ordered container.

```
struct myStruct {
    std::set<std::string> s1;
    std::set<std::string> s2;
};

std::string mergeAllStrings(const myStruct& ms) {
    static const std::string SEPARATOR = "#¤%&"; // Some uncommon sequence.
    std::string super;
    for (const auto& s : ms.s1) {
        super += s + SEPARATOR; // Append separator.
    }
    for (const auto& s : ms.s2) {
        super += s + SEPARATOR; // Append separator.
    }
    return super;
}

int main() {
    myStruct ms1{{"apple", "pear", "orange"}, {"red", "green", "blue"}};
    myStruct ms2{{"pear", "apple", "orange"}, {"red", "green", "blue"}};
    myStruct ms3{{"apple", "banana", "orange"}, {"red", "green", "blue"}};

    std::cout << std::hash<std::string>()(mergeAllStrings(ms1)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hash<std::string>()(mergeAllStrings(ms2)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hash<std::string>()(mergeAllStrings(ms3)) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
2681724430859750844 // Same
2681724430859750844 // Same
2942368903851914580 // Different
```

You can now create a hash functor e.g. as:

```
struct MyHash {
    std::size_t operator()(const myStruct& ms) const {
        return std::hash<std::string>()(mergeAllStrings(ms));
    }
};
```

and use it with `std::unordered_map` as:

```
std::unordered_map<myStruct, myValue, MyHash> m;
```

Note that you should provide a custom `equal_to` functor as well.

Comment: `myStruct ms4{{"applebananaorange"}, {"redgreenblue"}}; // whoops`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hmm, you're right. This solution doesn't work. Maybe it could add an otherwise rarely occuring separator character between each `std::string` :)

Comment: What if `std::set` is modified after it is inserted into the `unordered_map`?

Comment: @CahitGungor The `operator()` of `std::hash` takes a parameter `Key` each time it is called, and the hash is thus always generated from the updated `myStruct` object.

Comment: @Snpn: That would be a terribly non-robust way to do it. Why not hash both containers _properly_ and combine the two resulting hashes?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *"Why not hash both containers properly"*, well that's the question isn't it.