# Relative performance of using C++ Class based and struct based data type

Tags: c++, class, struct

Assuming the class in question is only used hold data fields which are directly accessed, which would be more performant to use, class or a struct with similar fields.

Comment: A `struct` is a `class` with all its members having public access. As such, there would be no performance difference.

Comment: You my friend need to master the art of searching in the web before programming, it will increase your results exponentially

Answer (score 4):

No. A `class` is the same exact thing as a `struct`, the only thing that changes is that, by default, `class` members are `private` and struct members are public.

There are also more changes related to inheritance and access type, but for more info on that check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585/when-should-you-use-a-class-vs-a-struct-in-c).

Comment: Inheritance is also public by default on a struct and private by default on a class, but who's counting?

Comment: @Salgar, yeah, I just added a link to that. Thx!