# when a class element from array is modified, it behaves like it is a copy, not reference

Tags: c++, reference

This is a simple thing that I'm not sure if it is possible in C++ like in some other languages. The thing behaves like it is a copy, but not the same object. I would expect that if this was struct, or some other value type - this would be expected behaviour, but for class, I expected this to behave like I'm looking at "reference", that is - the same object as is in array. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class someclass
{
    public:        
    void setn(int n2);
    int n=10;
};

void someclass::setn(int n2){
    n=n2;
};


int main()
{
  someclass moreofthem[5];   
  someclass my=moreofthem[1];  
  std::cout << "start value: " << my.n << " as inital\n"; //10
  my.setn(2);  
  std::cout << "new value: " << my.n << " as expected\n"; //2
  std::cout << "value in list: " << moreofthem[1].n << " why?\n";  //10?

}
```

Comment: seems like you think `class` and `struct` are two different concepts in C++. They are not. The only difference is their default access specifiers

Comment: I see now. Well, I had some experience with .NET, and I tried to play with C++ using the same concepts, but obviously will not work that way.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike C#, C++ makes no distinction between a `struct` and a `class`. In fact, the two are [completely interchangeable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54585/335858), and follow value semantic.

Fortunately, C++ also provides references and pointers as language constructs, which let you deal with references to instances of classes and structures:

```
 someclass moreofthem[5];   
 someclass& my = moreofthem[1];  
 //       ^
 //   That's it! Now you have yourself a reference
 std::cout << "start value: " << my.n << " as inital\n"; //10
 my.setn(2);
```

or if you prefer pointers

```
 someclass moreofthem[5];   
 someclass* my = &moreofthem[1];  
 //       ^      ^
 //   declare and use a pointer; note -> below
 std::cout << "start value: " << my.n << " as inital\n"; //10
 my->setn(2);
```

Unlike C#, where a `class` ensures that instances are handled through references (which represent a mix between C++ references and C++ pointers) C++ lets you decide how you want to handle your instances - by value, by reference, or by pointer. The behavior is close to C#'s `ref` parameter passing for objects of value type, but it is available in all contexts, including instance and local variables. This gives you more flexibility to handle the same object through a reference or by value in different contexts.

Answer (score 4):

That's because the object `my` ***is*** a copy of `moreofthem[1]`, not a reference.

If you want a reference you need to use the ampersand when defining the variable:

```
someclass& my=moreofthem[1];  
//       ^
// Note ampersand here
```

Answer (score 3):

> I would expect that if this was struct, or some other value type -
>   this would be expected behaviour, but for class, ...

The keywords `class` and `struct` can be used interchangeably. The only difference is that, if you don't specify an access modifer the default would
be :

- `public` in `struct`
- `private` in `class`

That said,

```
someclass& my=moreofthem[1];
```

makes a reference and that is what you're looking for. Here the reference `my` acts like an alias of the original variable `moreofthem[1]`