# Bus error: 10 in C++ while implementing singly linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, bus-error

I'm trying to implement a singly linked list on my own in C++ from scratch, having got so far with my first method append():

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ListNode{
    int key_value;
    ListNode *next;
};

class List{ 
    public:
        List();
        void append(int key);

    private:
        ListNode *head;
        ListNode *tail;
};

List::List(){
    head = NULL;
    tail = head;
}

void List::append(int key){
    ListNode *newnode;
    newnode->key_value = key;
    newnode->next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL){
        head = newnode;
        tail = head;
    }
    else{
        tail->next = newnode;
        tail = newnode;
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    try{ 
        List l1;
        l1.append(1);
        //l1.append(2);
        //l1.append(3);
        //l1.append(5);
    } 
    catch (exception const& ex) { 
        cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() <<endl; 
        return -1;
    } 
}
```

It compiles without any warnings or errors, but during execution I'm only getting the message `Bus error: 10`. Seems there is something wrong with the way I'm initializing and using the *ListNode* variables and pointers, any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: You are derefrencing `newnode` in `List::append` without first allocating a node.

Comment: You should consider increasing your warning level. Also after you are done understanding and correcting your code you should use `std::forward_list` or just `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I just looked up how to allocate structures and it worked. Seems I had initially tried to fix this via a solution on another thread but didn't realize that was about allocating a class object rather than a struct.

Comment: ***a class object rather than a struct.*** In c++ these are the same thing other than the default visibility.

Comment: Class object allocation looks like 'ListNode newnode = new ListNode()' while struct allocation looks like 'ListNode *newnode = new ListNode'. Right?

Comment: No they are the same. http://stackoverflow.com/a/54596/487892

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
ListNode *newnode;
```

you create uninitialized variable of pointer to `ListNode` and then you dereference it. Any access to unintialized variable leads to UB, but with pointers you most probably will get bus error immediatly. So allocate memory:

```
ListNode *newnode = new ListNode;
```

Note: instead of initializing data members:

```
newnode->key_value = key;
newnode->next = NULL;
```

you should provide proper constructor for `ListNode`:

```
struct ListNode {
    int key_value;
    ListNode *next;

    ListNode( int v ) : 
        key_value( v ),
        next( nullptr )
    {
    }
};
```

then just create it:

```
  ListNode *newnode = new ListNode( key );
```

and next 2 lines can be omitted. This will make your code cleaner and prevent from creating a `ListNode` instance with uninitialized data.

Note N2: as your class `List` has a raw pointer and ownership of the data you should follow [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) and create or disable copy ctor, assignment operator and dtor.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, code is cleaner and more maintainable that way.