# Trying to pass private structs defined inside another struct as parameter

Tags: c++, struct

I've been trying for quite a long time to pass a private struct, defined inside another struct, as a parameter to a function, but I always get the same error:

```
`cmt.h:17:85: error: expected identifier before ‘struct’
 template<typename C, typename D, typename T> bool existeClaveI(typename CMT<C,D,T>::struct Nodo *nodo, const C& clave);
cmt.h:17:85: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘struct’
cmt.h:17:104: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
 template<typename C, typename D, typename T> bool existeClaveI(typename CMT<C,D,T>::struct Nodo *nodo, const C& clave);´
```

My main struct is defined this way:

```
template<typename C, typename D, typename T> struct CMT{
    //friends...
    friend bool existeClave<C,D,T> (CMT<C,D,T>& cmt, const C& clave);
    friend bool existeClaveI<C,D,T> (typename CMT<C,D,T>::struct Nodo *nodo, const C& clave);

   private:
    struct Nodo{
        C clave;
        D dato;
        T tiempo;
        bool tieneTiempo;
        struct Nodo *izquierda;
        struct Nodo *derecha;
    };
    int numNodos;
    struct Nodo *raiz;
    Pila<struct Nodo*> iterador;
};
```

This is the function existeClaveI itself:

```
template<typename C, typename D, typename T>
bool existeClaveI(typename CMT<C,D,T>::struct Nodo *nodo, const C& clave){
...
}
```

How's the write way of specifying the parameters?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Just remove the `struct` keyword. The type is called `Nodo`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585/when-should-you-use-a-class-vs-a-struct-in-c

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o  I'm not allowed to use classes; it's a college assignment

Comment: @melpomene I've tried already that possibility, but I'm still getting the following compilation error: cmt.h:40:14: error: no type named ‘Nodo’ in ‘struct CMT<int, char, int>’
  friend bool existeClaveI<C,D,T> (typename CMT<C,D,T>::Nodo *nodo, const C& clave);

Comment: https://ideone.com/nXBzeP this compiles.