# C++ Range based loop for reading a structure

Tags: c++

I have kinda simple question, but I couldn't find any specific answer to this. 
So the question is: Let's say I have a vector with a structures inside. From the searches I have found out, that when we are reading classes in a vector, we should use an const auto&, like this

```
for (const auto& Class : Classes)
```

and for something like DWORD vectors it doesn't matter, but my question is, does it make sense to use the const auto& while working with structures? They don't have a constructor, but when using just auto, it should make a copy and make the loop slower, or more unefficient, or not?

Comment: *Hint: A struct is a class*

Comment: Ah I guess I'm retarded, I didn't realize that lol, sorry I guess

Comment: We don't need language like that, thank you.

Comment: So, your question is "why should we use `const auto&` instead of `const auto` in a ranged loop?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is no such thing as a structure in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36917400/560648).

Whether you write `struct` or `class`, you have created a *class*.

The classes created in both cases are equally capable of having a constructor.

So, yes. The advice is the same.