# Parts of a structure in C++

Tags: c++, class, struct, member-functions

Here is a code of a structure. On that there is a BSTree function included on the structure. I am stuck because I do not understand how a function can get called when is inside the structure. Here is the structure and if anyone can explain the trick would be helpful:

```
struct BSTree{

    int data;
    BSTree *left;
    BSTree *right;

    BSTree(int value){ 
        data = value;
        left = 0;
        right = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Show the whole snippet. Your question is unclear.

Comment: This is the whole structure of which will be used for a binary search tree where I need this structure to store the data and create the tree. But I do not understand why the function should be done inside the structure instead of outside it.

Comment: You need to pick up a good C++ book - this is completely basic C++ stuff (constructor and member functions).

Comment: The question you're trying to ask here is _"What is a constructor?"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no trick. In C++ `struct`s and `class`es can have data and function members.

The particular function you have there is a constructor, it's used to create an instance of the `struct`, an object of this type. A particular `struct` or `class` can have many constructors with different parameters, or no parameters at all.

```cpp
struct BSTree{

    int data;    
    BSTree *left;
    BSTree *right;
           
    BSTree(int value){ 
    data = value;
    left = 0;
    right = 0;
    }
};
```

This can then be used:

```
int main(){
  
   BSTree bst(3); //this will create a BSTree object where the data members are initialized
}                 //as stated in the constructor definition
```

This is just scratching the surface. You will need a good book to learn more about this. [**Here is a good list**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/6865932) you can pick from.

Comment: `struct` members are public by default.

Comment: @anastaciu what about in C? Can structures have function members on them?

Comment: @Bixo, unfortunately they can't, that would be nice though...

Comment: @anastaciu Thank you for making this clear because I was being confused with C and C++ and this gives the answer of my main problem. Because in C I know the structs create a new type of variable but when I saw it on C++ I thought they were the same as C. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

That's the definition of the [class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36917400/4386278)'s *constructor*.

It's a function called automatically when a `BSTree` instance is created.

You can read more in your C++ book.