# How do C structs wrapped in C++ classes interact when passed as a parameter of the same type as the struct?

Tags: c++, c, inheritance

Say I have the code below using the WINDOW struct from NCurses.

```
#include "ncurses.h"

class Window : public WINDOW {
    Window(int winHeight, int winWidth, int startX, int startY) {
        newwin(winHeight, winWidth, startX, startY);
    }
    void refresh() {
        wrefresh(this);
    }
};

int main() {
    initscr();

    Window win = Window(5, 5, 5, 5);
    win.refresh();

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a proper way to have C++ classes inherit C structs so that they can be passed as them, similar to how C++ classes that have inherited each other can?

Comment: in C++ a "C struct" is just a class. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585/when-should-you-use-a-class-vs-a-struct-in-c

Comment: Before even considering the possible answers: doing this goes against basic principles of good desgin. Do **NOT** inherit WINDOW, but make it a data member. Your Window class is not a ncurses handle.

Comment: ncurses doesn't seem to want to let you touch `WINDOW`s. In particular, `newwin` allocates the `WINDOW`s by itself, so there's not much point in trying to "replace" them with `Window`, since you're not in control of the object creation. If you want a "more C++" interface to the ncurses functions you want to *wrap* the *pointer*, not inherit from the structure.

Comment: I bet you can't inherit from a C base class, as in C, structs don't have vtables.

Comment: Well, simple inheritance is the way MFC (C++) classes like `CRect` embrace the old WinAPI (C) structures like `RECT`: `class CRect : public tagRECT {...` But those classes also provide an operator that returns a *pointer* to the inherited structure, such as `operator LPRECT();`.

Comment: @JosephLarson vtables aren't necessarily participating in inheritance, that's only for structs or classes with `virtual` functions, and C structs don't have functions, so there's no problem at all.

Comment: @spectras what's the correct way of allowing a class to be passed as a C struct?

Comment: @AdrianMole> MFC are not exactly an example of good object oriented-design though…

Comment: @WilliamB the correct way is to not allow that, and have a clean API instead.

Comment: @spectras Well, that's a matter of opinion. The underlying driving force behind MFC was to provide C++ *wrappers* for the existing, C-style WinAPI, etc. In that sense, it is both good and (reasonably) robust.

Comment: @AdrianMole , yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to do, create a wrapper, basically I want it so that when a Window object is passed as a parameter to something that takes a WINDOW struct it will give it the correct value rather then having to set a getter method for the window.

Comment: @WilliamB _"what's the correct way of allowing a class to be passed as a C struct?"_ Don't let other's confuse you here. There's nothing special to do with c structs in c++. They'll have the same names and memory layout as they'd have in c. If you declare them in a `extern "C" {}` block, there won't be any difference but the name mangling, and linking mangled or unmangled symbols always works with the c++ linker.

Comment: @AdrianMole> when you provide object-oriented wrappers, you might want them to follow the paradigm correctly. For instnace, having to call `foo->create()` instead of creating resources in the constructor, and `foo->destroy()` is plain bad design. In retrospect, of course; back then we did not have all the experience and feedback and it seemed reasonable. Does not mean it is a good example today.

Answer (score 1):

One way to create C++ 'wrappers' for structures defined in a C library, so that you can easily pass ***pointers*** to API calls in such a library is to emulate the way the MFC (Microsoft Foundation Class) library wraps GDI objects, such as the `RECT` structure, into classes like `CRect`.

MFC uses straightforward inheritance of the 'base' structure, and provides operators in each class that return pointers to the base structure (which will actually be a class instance's `this` pointer).

In the code below, I show the definition of the `RECT` structure and some excerpts of the `CRect` class, from the relevant Windows headers and MFC headers/source.

```c
// The "C" base structure, from "windef.h"
typedef struct tagRECT
{
    LONG    left;
    LONG    top;
    LONG    right;
    LONG    bottom;
} RECT, *LPRECT;

typedef const RECT *LPCRECT;
```

```cpp
class CRect : public tagRECT
{
public:
    CRect(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // Assign given parameters to base structure members...
        left = l; top = t; right = r; bottom = b;
    }
//...
    // Utility routines...
    int Width() const {
        return right - left;
    }
//...
    // convert between CRect and LPRECT/LPCRECT (no need for &)
    operator LPRECT() {
        return this;
    }
    operator LPCRECT() const {
        return this;
    }
//...
};
```

With wrapper classes defined like this, you can pass a `CRect` *object* (as in the comment above, no need for `&`) to a call from your C Library that expects a *pointer* to a `RECT`. For example, the [`GetWindowRect()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect) takes an `LPRECT` parameter and is called, from C, like this:

```c
HWND hWnd;
RECT rect;
BOOL answer = GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect); // Pass pointer to C structure
```

Using the `CRect` class, you can just pass the object, and the `LPRECT` operator will take care of the rest (but you can add the `&` if you really want to):

```cpp
HWND hWnd;
CRect rc;
BOOL answer = GetWindowRect(hWnd, rc);
```

There are limitations and caveats involved in this approach (e.g. horrid things may happen if the C library expects a `RECT` to be passed *by value*), but it may be an approach you find helpful.

Comment: Good answer, however CRect is not exactly from MFC. That class is defined in `<atltypes.h>` and it’s one of the many classes shared between MFC and ATL. It’s usable in both MFC projects, ATL projects, or stand-alone apps which don’t use either of them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/classes-shared-by-mfc-and-atl?view=msvc-160

Comment: If I understand the NCurses documentation correctly it takes WINDOW as a pointer, how would I have it recognize that?

Comment: @Soonts Well, I'm very old and, back in the old days, there was just MFC. ATL came along later (IIRC).

Comment: @WilliamB You can have your class inherit from `WINDOW` and then add an `operator WINDOW* ()` member that returns `this`. In the example I've shown (as it's Microsoft code), the `LPRECT` type is used, which is defined as a `RECT*` in the first code block. And, if all the library calls take a WINDOW *pointer*, then you should be reasonably safe using this approach.

Comment: @AdrianMole Not sure I’m much younger. That transition happened in Visual Studio 2002. Here’s what offline MSDN library says about them: “Beginning with Visual C++ .NET 2002, several existing MFC utility classes were rewritten or revised to reduce their dependencies on other MFC classes. These utility classes can now be used in any native C++ project.”

Comment: @AdrianMole But Window does not have the values requried by WINDOW *, when assigning a window in NCurses you do something like this,

WINDOW* win = newwin(5,5,5,5);

this just returning this gives an error.

Comment: @WilliamB Then perhaps, as suggested in the comments to your question, your should have a `WINDOW` as a data member of your class, rather than use inheritance. That way, you can readily assign it in the class constructor and **still** use the pointer to `this` as a pointer to a `WINDOW` ... ***so long as the WINDOW is the first data member of your class***.