# Initializer list for struct deriving from class (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, initializer-list

Can you tell me what is wrong in the following example? I am using C++17, where I thought the following should be supported.

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    int m1;
};

int main() {
    /* Results in a compilation error 
     * error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Derived'
     * message : No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous */
    Derived d{ {},1 };
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Derived` isn't an aggregate, since it has a base class with virtual members. So it can't be initialized as an aggregate.

Comment: Removing the virtual destructor in Base does result in the same compilation error, why so? (And I guess this would be a dangerous solution...)

Comment: Which version of MSVC do you use? Have you tried to explicitly set C++17 mode (`/std:c++17`)?

Comment: fwiw, the difference between `struct` and `class` is not relevant for your issue. You'd get the same with `class Derived : public Base { public: int m1; };` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585/when-should-you-use-a-class-vs-a-struct-in-c

Comment: @user - Not having a virtual destrutor is dangerous **only** if you delete a Derived through a pointer to Base. As you don't use `new` and `delete`, nothing bad happens. Also, in VS2022 the code compiles fine (without the destructor).

Comment: FYI: Without the `Base` constructor and the `/std:c++17` added, the code [builds fine](https://godbolt.org/z/veWzTfM4c) with MSVC 19.29.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! I needed to add `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` and `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)` to set it to C++ 17 explicitly and remove the virtual destructor in Base.

I will use shared_ptrs of Derived and pass them around as shared_ptrs of Base. I guess for this I will need to explicitely implement a constructor to use initialization lists?

Comment: Actually you *don't* need an `std::initializer_list` constructor. The compiler should pick the correct constructor if you declare one. And then you don't need to initialize the base-class in the definition of `d`: `Derived d{1};` (with a suitable `Derived(int)` constructor) will be enough.

Comment: Great thanks. `Base` stays as it is, and for `Derived` I will implement a suitable Constructor. 
I will answer the question and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because `Derived` is not an aggregate since it has a base class with virtual members.

The code compiles and runs when removing the virtual destructor in `Base` and using `C++17`.

If `Base` requires a virtual destructor, `Derived` can implement a custom constructor allowing initialization using curly brackets.

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived(int m): m1(m) {}
    int m1;
};

int main() {
    Derived d{ 1 };
    return 0;
}
```