# Struct to Class

Tags: c++, class, struct, linked-list, scope

I'm trying to convert a c program to c++ basically a struct data type to a class but is keeps showing "  ‘first’ was not declared in this scope". whereas c program is working just fine.

**Original code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
 int data;
 struct Node *next;
}*first=NULL;

void Display(struct Node *p)
{
 while(p!=NULL)
 {
 printf("%d ",p->data);
 p=p->next;
 }
}   


void Insert(struct Node *p,int index,int x)
{
 struct Node *t;
 int i;
 
 if(index < 0 || index > 9)
 return;
 t=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
 t->data=x;
 
 if(index == 0)
 {
 t->next=first;
 first=t;
 }
 else
 {
 for(i=0;i<index-1;i++)
 p=p->next;
 t->next=p->next;
 p->next=t;
 
 }
 
 
}
int main()
{
 Insert(first,0,5);
 Insert(first,1,10);
 Insert(first,2,15);
 Display(first);
 return 0;
}
```

**edited Code**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

void Display(struct Node *p){
    while(p!=NULL){
        std::cout << p->data << std::endl;
        p=p->next;
    }
}   


void Insert(struct Node *p,int index,int x){
    Node *t;
    int i;
     
    if(index < 0 || index > 9)
    return;
    t=new Node;
    t->data=x;
 
    if(index == 0){
        t->next=first;
        first=t;
    }
    else
    {
    for(i=0;i<index-1;i++)
    p=p->next;
    t->next=p->next;
    p->next=t;
 
 }
 
 
}
int main()
{
 Node *first=NULL;  // 
 Insert(first,1,10);
 Insert(first,2,15);
 Display(first);
 return 0;
}
```

**error is something related to** "Node *first = Null" **line something to do with global pointer**
Insert(first,0,5);

[**error I'm getting.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIzFx.png)

Comment: `class` and `struct` are two different keywords to declare a class. Only difference is default access. The error you get has nothing to do with swapping the two keywords. Please include the compiler error message as text in the question

Comment: in the c code you have a global `}*first=NULL;` in the c++ code you moved it to `main`. Voting to close as typo, though this is also relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585/when-should-you-use-a-class-vs-a-struct-in-c

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, Not removed, but moved to `main`. To me, that makes it more likely to be a question about scope.

Comment: @chris not sure whats the question is really about. OP seems to know already that the issue is a global pointer, but at the same time suggests that the only change is struct to class

Comment: In case it's not clear, one solution is simply to put `first` back where you found it. `class Node { ... } *first = NULL;` is legal C++, though for many reasons not very good C++. And of course `struct` is perfectly legal in C++ too.

Comment: Shouldn't conversion uses `std::list<int>` or `std::vector<int>` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GMb7Tx5ca).

Answer (score 0):

In the C program you declared variable `first` in the file scope.

```
struct Node
{
 int data;
 struct Node *next;
}*first=NULL;
```

So it is visible in all functions defined after the structure definition.

In the C++ program you declared the variable `first` in a block scope of main

```
int main()
{
 Node *first=NULL; 
 //...
```

So it is invisible inside the function `Insert` in this code snippet

```
if(index == 0){
    t->next=first;
    first=t;
}
```

In any case the function `Insert` is invalid because at least there is no check whether `p` is equal to `nullptr` in this for loop

```
for(i=0;i<index-1;i++)
p=p->next;
```

that can result in undefined behavior.

The first function parameter should have a referenced type as for example

```
void Insert(struct Node * &p,int index,int x){
```

In this case you could write for example

```
if(index == 0){
    t->next=p;
    p=t;
}
```

and the pointer first defined in main will be changed.

And if you want to rewrite the list in C++ then the provided functions should be declared as member functions of the class.

Comment: As extra note, C++ already has `std::list` (and `std::vector`).