# Why we use `class` when there's `struct` in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why use `class` instead of `struct` in C++ when they have only minor differences in access control?

I have consulted many sources, including videos and books, but have not found relevant information. The materials only explain their relationship, but do not elaborate on why `class` was introduced. Can't object-oriented programming be done using `struct`？

Comment: "The materials only explain their relationship" if you know the difference between the two keywords, you already know all there is to know. When to use one vs the other to define a class is matter of personal preference and opinions

Comment: You consulted some absolutely lousy books, then. The videos not being informative is not surprising. But there are many [good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?r=Saves_AllUserSaves) that would have explained this.

Comment: TLDR: The choice of `struct` vs. `class` often communicates the *intent* of the given structure, be it "dumb data" or "encapsulated object".

Comment: IMHO, there is `class` because a lot of Object Oriented Design and Programming use the concept of classes rather than structs.  The `struct` was kept to make transitioning from C a lot easier.

Comment: In a way struct and class are equivalent a struct's members are public by default, and a class' members are private by default. But generally structs are used to represent data and classes represent data+operations+invariants

Comment: Branding, it's a new language, it needs a new keyword.

Comment: Side note: what a contrast that is symptomatic of SO evolution! In the duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/q/54585 from 2008: 1266 votes, while this one, asking essentially the same thing in 2024: -5 votes!

Comment: Brief history of `class` origins in C++: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/411507/248591